# Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I need some help with the select tag helper in ASP.NET Core.

I have a list of employees that I'm trying to bind to a select tag helper. My employees are in a `List<Employee> EmployeesList` and selected value will go into `EmployeeId` property. My view model looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public string Comments { get; set; }
   public List<Employee> EmployeesList {get; set; }
}
```

My employee class looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how do I tell my select tag helper to use the `Id` as the value while displaying `FullName` in the drop down list?

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="???" />
```

I'd appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: just something i thought i should add, it appears not to work if you close the select tag immediately always close the tags with </select> the tag helper did not work with  <select asp-for.....  />

Comment: just a tip. scaffolding controllers show generally show you the best ways to such things

Comment: @RoughPlace, thanks for the tip.  That's what helped me

Answer (score 534, accepted):

#### Using the Select Tag helpers to render a SELECT element

In your GET action, create an object of your view model, load the `EmployeeList` collection property and send that to the view.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.EmployeesList = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { Id = 1, FullName = "Shyju" },
        new Employee { Id = 2, FullName = "Bryan" }
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

And in your create view, create a new `SelectList` object from the `EmployeeList` property and pass that as value for the `asp-items` property.

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create">

    <select asp-for="EmployeeId" 
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList, nameof(Employee.Id), nameof(Employee.FullName)))">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

And your HttpPost action method to accept the submitted form data.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
{
   //  check model.EmployeeId 
   //  to do : Save and redirect
}
```

**Or**

If your view model has a `List<SelectListItem>` as the property for your dropdown items.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }
}
```

And in your get action,

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.Employees = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Shyju", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Sean", Value = "2"}
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

And in the view, you can directly use the `Employees` property for the `asp-items`.

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create">

    <label>Comments</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Comments"/>

    <label>Lucky Employee</label>
    <select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@Model.Employees" >
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

The class `SelectListItem` belongs to `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering` namespace.

Make sure you are using an explicit closing tag for the select element. If you use the self closing tag approach, the tag helper will render an empty SELECT element!

The below approach **will not work**

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@Model.Employees" />
```

But this will work.

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@Model.Employees"></select>
```

---

#### Getting data from your database table using entity framework

The above examples are using hard coded items for the options. So i thought i will add some sample code to get data using Entity framework as a lot of people use that.

Let's assume your DbContext object has a property called `Employees`, which is of type `DbSet<Employee>` where the `Employee` entity class has an `Id` and `Name` property like this

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { set; get; }
   public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

You can use a LINQ query to get the employees and use the Select method in your LINQ expression to create a list of `SelectListItem` objects for each employee.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.Employees = context.Employees
                          .Select(a => new SelectListItem() {  
                              Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                              Text = a.Name
                          })
                          .ToList();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `context` is your db context object. The view code is same as above.

#### Using SelectList

Some people prefer to use `SelectList` class to hold the items needed to render the options.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Employees { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you can use the `SelectList` constructor to populate the `Employees` property of the view model. Make sure you are specifying the  `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` parameters. You can use a [nameof expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) to link the field names statically.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.Employees = new SelectList(GetEmployees(), nameof(Employee.Id), nameof(Employee.FirstName));
    return View(vm);
}
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    // hard coded list for demo. 
    // You may replace with real data from database to create Employee objects
    return new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { Id = 1, FirstName = "Shyju" },
        new Employee { Id = 2, FirstName = "Bryan" }
    };
}
```

Here I am calling the `GetEmployees` method to get a list of Employee objects, each with an `Id` and `FirstName` property and I use those properties as `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` of the `SelectList` object we created. You can change the hardcoded list to a code which reads data from a database table.

The view code will be same.

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@Model.Employees" >
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

#### Render a SELECT element from a list of strings.

Sometimes you might want to render a select element from a list of strings. In that case, you can use the `SelectList` constructor which only takes `IEnumerable<T>`

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();
var items = new List<string> {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"};
vm.Employees = new SelectList(items);
return View(vm);
```

The view code will be same.

#### Setting selected options

Some times,you might want to set one option as the default option in the SELECT element (For example, in an edit screen, you want to load the previously saved option value). To do that, you may simply set the `EmployeeId` property value to the value of the option you want to be selected.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.Employees = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Shyju", Value = "11"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Tom", Value = "12"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Jerry", Value = "13"}
    };
    vm.EmployeeId = 12;  // Here you set the value
    return View(vm);
}
```

This will select the option Tom in the select element when the page is rendered.

#### Multi select dropdown

If you want to render a multi select dropdown, you can simply change your view model property which you use for `asp-for` attribute in your view to an array type.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int[] EmployeeIds { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }
}
```

This will render the HTML markup for the select element with the `multiple` attribute which will allow the user to select multiple options.

```
@model MyViewModel
<select id="EmployeeIds" multiple="multiple" name="EmployeeIds">
    <option>Please select one</option>
    <option value="1">Shyju</option>
    <option value="2">Sean</option>
</select>
```

#### Setting selected options in multi select

Similar to single select, set the `EmployeeIds` property value to the an array of values you want.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.Employees = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Shyju", Value = "11"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Tom", Value = "12"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Jerry", Value = "13"}
    };
    vm.EmployeeIds= new int[] { 12,13} ;  
    return View(vm);
}
```

This will select the option Tom and Jerry in the multi select element when the page is rendered.

#### Using ViewBag to transfer the list of items

If you do not prefer to keep a collection type property to pass the list of options to the view, you can use the dynamic ViewBag to do so.(*This is not my personally recommended approach as viewbag is dynamic and your code is prone to uncaught typo errors*)

```
public IActionResult Create()
{       
    ViewBag.Employees = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Shyju", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Sean", Value = "2"}
    };
    return View(new MyViewModel());
}
```

and in the view

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Employees">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

#### Using ViewBag to transfer the list of items and setting selected option

It is same as above. All you have to do is, set the property (for which you are binding the dropdown for) value to the value of the option you want to be selected.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{       
    ViewBag.Employees = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Shyju", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Bryan", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Sean", Value = "3"}
    };

    vm.EmployeeId = 2;  // This will set Bryan as selected

    return View(new MyViewModel());
}
```

and in the view

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Employees">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

#### Grouping items

The select tag helper method supports grouping options in a dropdown. All you have to do is, specify the  `Group` property value of each `SelectListItem` in your action method.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
   
    var group1 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Dev Team" };
    var group2 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "QA Team" };

    var employeeList = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Shyju", Group = group1 },
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Bryan", Group = group1 },
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Kevin", Group = group2 },
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Alex", Group = group2 }
    };
    vm.Employees = employeeList;
    return View(vm);
}
```

There is no change in the view code. the select tag helper will now render the options inside 2 [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) items.

Comment: Thank you! Kind of like the old razor syntax where we need to perform a conversion to SelectList. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! If you use a `List<SelectListItem>` as the property in your view model, You don't need to convert it in the view. See my updated in the answer.

Comment: @Shyju Does this `List<SelectListItem>` property type has to be in the corresponding model class (Emoplyee class in this post), as well?

Comment: No.It is in the view model and we use view model to build the select element. We are not using the entity class in the view.

Comment: I was looking for how to add an empty option, thanks for using `<option>Please select one</option>`

Comment: Question: `asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countries">` seems to work instead of `asp-items="@(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countries">`, which one is preferable?

Comment: I get an error on @model MyViewModel stating that MyViewModel doesn't exist.   I copied your class and pasted it into HomeController.cs and I added your Create() to that file as well.  I'm new to this, but I seem to be missing something huge with .net core.   I can write this all in asp.net in minutes and I'm spending hours trying to make it work for Linux asp.net core.   This is starting to irritate the hell out of me.

Comment: Note that you MUST have a closing </select> tag - it won't work if you try to self-close the select tag like <select ... />.  Also, if you use an empty option like "Please select one", you need to give it a value of empty string "" in order for required field validation to work.

Comment: Is there a directive or assembly reference for IActionResult? I get an error.

Comment: <select class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.Roles"></select> doesn't work for me. Roles is a List<SelectListIem>.

Comment: Pff, I wasn't returning my model, LOL.

Comment: "Make sure you are using an explicit closing tag for the select element. If you use the self closing tag approach, the tag helper will render an empty SELECT element!"

This was the issue in my case. Cheers!

Comment: Minor nitpick ```asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList,"Id","FullName"))"``` could be changed to ```asp-items="new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList, nameof(Employee.Id), nameof(Employee.FullName))"```. If you do need to use a string constant inside a html attribute, you can use single quotes for the attribute to avoid the ```@()```

Comment: "Using ViewBag to transfer the list of items and setting selected option": The `asp-for` cannot be used like this. It's an error. I need to find another solution.

Comment: `asp-for` value is still your property name. What error are you running into ?

Comment: for some reason, if I put a space before the "=" sign in "asp-items=... etc.", the list shows empty (no errors). Took me almost an hour to find the problem. Using AspNetCore.App 2.2.6, AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.2.0, .NETCore.App 2.2.6

Comment: @Andy Or you can make the int? nullable, this also makes required validation work, it passes null through as the value rather than 0, which triggers the required validation.

Comment: Brilliant. Extra kudos for saying what namespace `SelectList` is in.  Hardly anyone ever does!

Answer (score 15):

I created an Interface and a `<options>` tag helper for this. So I didn't have to convert the `IEnumerable<T>` items into `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` every time I have to populate the `<select>` control.

And I think it works beautifully...

The usage is something like:

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <options asp-items="@Model.EmployeesList" />
</select>
```

And to make it work with the tag helper you have to implement that interface in your class:

```
public class Employee : IIntegerListItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }

   public int Value { return Id; }
   public string Text{ return FullName ; }
}
```

---

These are the needed codes:

The interface:

```
public interface IIntegerListItem
{
    int Value { get; }
    string Text { get; }
}
```

The `<options>` tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("options", Attributes = "asp-items")]
public class OptionsTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public OptionsTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        Generator = generator;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public IHtmlGenerator Generator { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-items")]
    public object Items { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.SuppressOutput();
        // Is this <options /> element a child of a <select/> element the SelectTagHelper targeted?
        object formDataEntry;
        context.Items.TryGetValue(typeof(SelectTagHelper), out formDataEntry);

        var selectedValues = formDataEntry as ICollection<string>;
        var encodedValues = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (selectedValues != null && selectedValues.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var selectedValue in selectedValues)
            {
                encodedValues.Add(Generator.Encode(selectedValue));
            }
        }

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = null;
        if (Items != null)
        {
            if (Items is IEnumerable)
            {
                var enumerable = Items as IEnumerable;
                if (Items is IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                    items = Items as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
                else if (Items is IEnumerable<IIntegerListItem>)
                    items = ((IEnumerable<IIntegerListItem>)Items).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Selected = false, Value = ((IIntegerListItem)x).Value.ToString(), Text = ((IIntegerListItem)x).Text });
                else
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The {2} was unable to provide metadata about '{1}' expression value '{3}' for <options>.",
                        "<options>",
                        "ForAttributeName",
                        nameof(IModelMetadataProvider),
                        "For.Name"));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid items for <options>");
            }

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                bool selected = (selectedValues != null && selectedValues.Contains(item.Value)) || encodedValues.Contains(item.Value);
                var selectedAttr = selected ? "selected='selected'" : "";

                if (item.Value != null)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml($"<option value='{item.Value}' {selectedAttr}>{item.Text}</option>");
                else
                    output.Content.AppendHtml($"<option>{item.Text}</option>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*There may be some typo but the aim is clear I think. I had to edit a little bit.*

Answer (score 7):

My answer below **doesn't** solve the question but it *relates* to.

If someone is using `enum` instead of a class model, like this example:

```
public enum Counter
{
    [Display(Name = "Number 1")]
    No1 = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Number 2")]
    No2 = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Number 3")]
    No3 = 3
}
```

And a property to get the value when submiting:

```
public int No { get; set; }
```

In the razor page, you can use `Html.GetEnumSelectList<Counter>()` to get the enum properties.

```
<select asp-for="No" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Counter>()"></select>
```

It generates the following HTML:

```
<select id="No" name="No">
    <option value="1">Number 1</option>
    <option value="2">Number 2</option>
    <option value="3">Number 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use **IHtmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList.**

```
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a select list for the given TEnum.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   TEnum:
    //     Type to generate a select list for.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 containing the select list for the
    //     given TEnum.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ArgumentException:
    //     Thrown if TEnum is not an System.Enum or if it has a System.FlagsAttribute.
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code for **multiple select**:

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId"  multiple="multiple" asp-items="@ViewBag.Employees">
    <option>Please select</option>
</select>
```

You can also use:

```
<select id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId"  multiple="multiple" asp-items="@ViewBag.Employees">
    <option>Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Get:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["Tags"] = new SelectList(_context.Tags, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

In Post:

```
var selectedIds= Request.Form["Tags"];
```

In View :

```
<label>Tags</label>
<select  asp-for="Tags"  id="Tags" name="Tags" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Tags" multiple></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`asp-items` requires some collection of instances of `SelectListItem` class (from namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering) which contains `Text` and `Value` properties. So you can convert your Employees collection to required that way f.e. `employees.Select(e => new SelectListItem(e.FullName, e.Id.ToString()))` and put result to `asp-items` attribute.