# MVC 6 - TagHelper Select

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

This may be a stupid question but I do not know why this is the default behavior for the Select TagHelper.

This is what I have in my view

```
<select asp-for="Estimators" asp-items="Model.Estimators" class="form-control"></select>
```

and this is the output on the page

```
<select class="form-control" id="Estimators" multiple="multiple" name="Estimators"><option value="2">Enio LastName</option>
<option value="6">Ianko Diaz</option>
<option value="7">Iordan Diaz</option>
<option value="8">Joan Alonso</option>
<option value="5">Lazaro Araya</option>
<option value="3">Leydis Martinez</option>
<option value="4">Ruben Cruz</option>
<option value="1">Shamir Ajate</option>
<option value="9">Yudiel Curbelo</option>
</select>
```

why is the select tag rendering as multiple="multiple".

Answer (score 7):

You are actually using the helper wrong. You should have another property to store the selected item.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
   public int SelectedEstimator { set; get; }
   public List<SelectListItem> Estimators { set; get; }
}
```

And in your view

```
@model YourViewModel
<select asp-for="SelectedEstimator" asp-items="@Model.Estimators">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

This will render a single selectable SELECT element.

When the property you use for `asp-for` items is of array type, the generated select element will be multi select.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
   public int[] SelectedEstimator { set; get; }
   public List<SelectListItem> Estimators { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Here is my property. public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Estimators { get; set; }

Comment: @YudielCurbelo You are using the helper in a wrong way. See my answer which explains how to use it.  Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6/34624217#34624217) answer for more detailed sample.

Comment: @YudielCurbelo You may have forgotten to mark this response from @Shyju as `Answer`. You may want to do that for the benefit of other users.