# How can I add an array type to my database using EF7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 6 and Entity Framework 7.

My Model:

```
public class Contact {

    public int[] SelectedEstimator { set; get; }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'SelectedEstimator'
on entity type 'ContactsManagerV3.Models.Contact' 
has not been added to the model or ignored.
```

If I change the SelectedEstimator property to an int, it works. How can I get int[] to work?

I was trying to follow [MVC 6 - TagHelper Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110217/mvc-6-taghelper-select)

Comment: Have you added the contract class in the EF Databasecontext?

Comment: In the example you link to, that's just a view model, not an EF POCO (at least from what I can see). SQL has no native support for arrays, so I don't see how it could be mapped to for use by EF.

Comment: What db type do you expect it to be?

Comment: @MartinCostello That's what I figured. I'm a total newbie, so it's been hard to wrap my head around everything. I'm going to go learn about View Models.

Comment: @CamBruce Some sort of array, but I guess the database does not support this datatype. Then that's the problem.

Comment: @EugeneFedotov database support it ! my ans sectection there have a link . that can be help you but you must be set primary key not array

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a column of `int[]` type ( in fact can't be any type of array), which is what you are trying to do with the `SelectedEstimator` property. You can follow this answer ([How to store double[] array to database with Entity Framework Code-First approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220921/how-to-store-double-array-to-database-with-entity-framework-code-first-approac)) where they transform the array to string to save the array and then from string to array to take it or you can do something like this:

```
public class Estimator{

      public int EstimatorId {get;set;}

      public int Value {get;set;}

      public int ContactId {get;set;}

      public Contact Contact {get;set;}
}

public class Contact {

      public int ContactId {get;set;}

      public ICollection<Estimator> SelectedEstimator { set; get; }   

}
```

Now you can accomplish what you want selecting the `Estimator.Value`. Hope it helps