# MVC6 Select Tag Helper & Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have a model class with a relationship to another, as per below:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Industry Industry { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Head Office")]
    public string HeadOffice { get; set; }
}

public class Industry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Industry name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    [Display(Name="Industry")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The ultimate goal is that on the Client CRUD views I can also select the Industry.Name, or to assign it when editing/creating.

I have managed to select the dropdown list data using the following in the controller:

```
private void PopulateIndustriesDropDownList(object selectedIndustry = null)
{
    var industriesQuery = from i in _context.Industry
                          orderby i.Name
                          select i.Name;
    ViewBag.Industries = new SelectList(industriesQuery, "Industry", "Name", selectedIndustry);
}
```

And I have the following in each of my controller functions:

```
// GET: Clients/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    PopulateIndustriesDropDownList();
    return View();
}

// POST: Clients/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Client.Add(client);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    PopulateIndustriesDropDownList();
    return View(client);
}
```

Everything appears to work ok, but I cannot work out how to bind this in my view. This is my first time working with Tag Helpers and I am sure my syntax isn't correct.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Industry.Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="Industry.ID" asp-items="ViewBag.Industries" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When calling the Edit function, I don't get an error but the dropdown list doesn't get populated with anything.

Can anyone please point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see (though I am not sure) you should put asp-items="@ViewBag.Industries" instead of asp-items="ViewBag.Industries".
I believe that you have detailed explanation here:
[Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6)

Comment: Thanks Nemanja however this still didn't work. I have been reading up further and it may be that I am better to have a ViewModel rather than linking the Model directly to the View. I'm going to test this out to see if it fits my needs more.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the select tag helper expects an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`
Refactor your PopulateIndustriesDropDownList method to

```
ViewBag.Industries = new SelectList(industriesQuery, "Industry", "Name", selectedIndustry).Items;
```

or do the cast in the view,