# ASP.Net 5 MVC6 select taghelper produces wrong output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I modified the default login of asp.net mvc 6 and wanted to add a dropdown-list with taghelper `select` but it seems like it produces a wrong output.

I added the select-taghelper-element so it looks like this:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Tenant" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="Tenant" asp-items="ViewBag.Tenants" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Tenant" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

after adding the select-tag, the submit-button is not displayed anymore - the dropdown is displayed but contains no data, but using breakpoints Viewbag.Tenants contains data.
When I remove the first div with the select-tag, the button is showing.

Any idea what here is wrong?

Comment: have you tried with an @ before ViewBag?

Comment: @JoeAudette thanks, tried, makes no difference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is wrong. Do not use the self closing `select` tag. Have an explicit closing tag.

This should work.

```
<select asp-for="Tenant" asp-items="ViewBag.Tenants" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Ahh you're a genius! Thanks! :)

Comment: I have tried this and weirdly I get the list rendered with multiple="multiple" as a select list rather than a dropdownlist?

Comment: @MarkRedman It depends on the type of the property you use for `asp-for` If it is an array type (`int[]`/`string[]`), It will be rendered with multiple attribute

Comment: Its a SelectList type, I have tried both SelectList and List<SelectListItem> (not IEnumerable or an array)

Comment: I am talking about the property used for `asp-for` not `asp-items`. See [Select Tag Helper in MVC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6/34624217#34624217)