# Select Tag Helper binding with an array or list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

How can my following controller Action Method bind a list of integers to a `Select Tag Helper` in my ASP.NET Core project `without using ModelView`? Or, without ModelView this cannot be done?

**Action Method**:

```
public IActionResult ListofDays()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> DaysList = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).ToList();
            return View(DaysList);
        }
```

**Select Tag**:

```
<select asp-for="???" asp-items="???"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the int array to a list of `SelectListItem` which can be used as your `asp-items` property value of select tag helper.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var daysList =Enumerable.Range(1, 7)
       .Select(g => new SelectListItem {Value = g.ToString(), Text =g.ToString()}).ToList();
    return View(daysList);
}
```

Now in the view which is strongly typed to a list of `SelectListItem`,

```
@model List<SelectListItem>
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
    <select name="MyDay" asp-items="Model"></select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When you submit the form, the selected day will be in the `MyDay` form element. You may use a parameter with the same name in your HttpPost action method to receive it.

For your reference :
[Select Tag Helper in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. What would be the `@model` declaration in the view? I tried `@model List<int>` but that does not work.

Comment: Sorry ! I missed that part. It should be a collection/list of `SelectListItem` as i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: It works. Thank you - specially for explaining your solution properly and adding a reference to your another response as I use that for other `Select Tag Helper` scenarios.