# Replicate Html.DropDownListFor(..., optionLabel, ...) with SelectTagHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to replicate the functionality of the `optionLabel` argument from `Html.DropDownListFor` with `<select> TagHelper`. I have a `Model.Variable` that can be `null` or have a `value` *(and when it does, the null-selection `<option>` with that value name shows)*.

The `DropDownListFor` works but the `<select>` equivalent ignores my `asp-option-label="Model.Variable"`. I also looked at the [SelectTagHelper's code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/bb226aef6be3e91c23e4ced99a6b8baae4fceac8/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/SelectTagHelper.cs) and the `optionLabel` argument seems to be unused.

Can this be done with the `<select> TagHelper` or should I just stick to `Html.DropDownListFor`?

Comment: so which part is not working with the select tag helper ? Did you see [Select Tag Helper in MVC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6)

Comment: @Shyju I need the empty `<option>` to be present only if I need it too. Not always, not never, only when `Model.Var` is not null, just like `optionLabel`'s default functionality. The second paragraph clearly states what is not working...