# HTML.DropDownListFor DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Database to an HTML  instead of retrieving to the Html.DropDownListFor but I'm unable to retrieve to  tag.

**NewCustomerViewModel**

```
    public class NewCustomerViewModel
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private CustomerDbContext _context;

    public CustomerController(CustomerDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Customers.ToList());
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var stateNames = _context.States.ToList();
        var viewModel = new NewCustomerViewModel
        {
            States = stateNames
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customer);
    }
}
```

**Create View**

The HTML DropDownListFor below works fine:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StId, new SelectList(Model.States, "StId", "StName"))
```

I'm unable to get the select tag to work though.

```
<select asp-for="StId" asp-items="@Model.States" class="form-control">
            <option>Select State</option>
        </select>
```

All of my HTML in my Create view using  and  rather than the HTML Helpers which is what I'm trying to avoid. I would just like to be able to retrieve the data to the  tag instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the select tag helper, `asp-items` expects `SelectListItem` collection\SelectList, and each item in that has a `Value` and `Text` property. The `Value` properties value will be used for the option's value and `Text` propertiesvalue will be used for the display text of the option in the UI.

Items in your `States` collection does not have a Value and Text property, but has `StId` and `StName` property. So we need to convert this type to SelectListItem type.

So your code should be

```
<select asp-for="StId"  asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.States,"StId","StName"))">
     <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

Additional reference

[Select Tag Helper in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6)

Comment: Thank you!! That worked. I have a couple questions, what does the "@"symbol do and why is it needed?

Comment: Would I be better off retrieving the Value and ID data for my DropDownList in my Controller this way rather than the other way? If so, what would I need to add to the Create Action Method and SelectTag Helper?

`private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStateList()
        {
            var ste = _context.State
                .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = s.StId.ToString(),
                    Text = s.StName
                })
                .ToList();

            return (ste);
        }`

Comment: you need `@` because we want to execute some C# code (creating new SelectList object). I personally prefer to keep less C# code in views. See the link i posted,It has different approaches. I prefer the one with less C# code(no `new SelectList` in view)

Comment: Ok, since I have implemented the ViewModel and DropDownList either using select tag helper or html.dropdownfor I keep getting the error when I try to execute the Create Action Method.

**Error:**
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items `<select asp-for="StId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.States,"StId","StAbbr"))">`

Comment: in your GET action ? Are you sure `Model.States` is a valid collection ? (not null)

Comment: sorry, not sure I fully understand what you mean by valid collection :(

Comment: I set a breakpoint on `var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel` and in the GET action and `viewModel` is NULL. What's odd though is that the values from the GET action get bound to the DropDownList.