# Passing SelectList along with model in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My AppUser class contains following property

```
 public string UserName { get; set; }
 public string Email { get; set; }
 public Cities City { get; set; }
```

where Cities is an enum contains cities of AppUsers.

While i creating CRUD action methods for this user, i want to populate these cities as dropdownlist in my Views(I can convert enum to SelectList).
I tried to create a Viewmodel containing Cities enum as property, but for my edit action i am using direct AppUser as model. Here i can't populate them as Dropdownlist in Edit view.

In short, Without adding Cities to the user(viewmodel) class how can we pass SelectList to View. Tried Tempdata, Viewdata Viewbag but they disappear when app getting validation errors.

Comment: Sorry ! Little unclear what you are asking ? Are yo having trouble rendering the SELECT element ? How does your view code looks like ?

Comment: Also take a look at [Select Tag Helper in MVC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-mvc-6/34624217#34624217)

Comment: Without adding Cities to the user(viewmodel) class how can we pass SelectList to View.

Comment: You can use ViewBag to pass a list of cities to build the dropdown. But you need a property to hold the selected city option value. see the link i posted which has an example with ViewBag being used to transfer data

Comment: ViewBag loosing data once it has been read. But i am posting to same page when getting validation errors then dropdownlist shows empty.

Comment: A 'bit' late to the party, but why wouldn't you add it to the viewmodel? The viewmodels are supposed to handle this and your original entities won't suffer for it.
If you used your viewmodel somewhere else as well but in a different way, then it's better to make an extra viewmodel that contains slightly different data but suits the view you're trying to populate.