# Getting null value from select list(dropdownList)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Trying to get the Id of a selected item. But I am getting null value from it.

### This is my view for creating a room where to select room type

```
<select asp-for="RoomType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.roomType, "Id", "Type"))" class="form-control">
    <option>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

This is my models

```
public class RoomModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public RoomTypeViewModel RoomType { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class RoomTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateRoom()
{
    ViewBag.roomType = _context.RoomType.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Does asp-items need @, it is not a razor code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying data in a SelectList in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835452/displaying-data-in-a-selectlist-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: actually I'm trying to bind the ViewBag data to the dropdown. Because I'm using two model in this 'view' @Bosco.

Comment: When do you get null value?

Comment: I don't know somethings so weird. Code is now working. I just change in model RoomTypeViewModel to int . Then it worked. But while I again change the type from int to 'RoomTypeViewModel' and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have of the item you want to put on the dropdown list like this.

**Controller.cs**

```
public class RoomController : Controller
{
     private readyonly RoomTypeContext _contextRoomType;
}

public RoomController(RoomTypeContext contextRoomType)
{
     _contextRoomType = contextRoomType;
}

public IActionResult Create()
{
     List<RoomType> roomTypes = new List<RoomType>();
     roomTypes = (from room in _contextRoomType.roomTypes select room).ToList();
     roomTypes.Insert(0, new RoomType { });
     ViewBag.ListOfRoomTypes = roomTypes;
}
```

**View.cshtml**

```
<select asp-for="RoomType" 
        class="form-control form-control-sm" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListOfRoomTypes , "Id","Type"))">
</select>
```