# Passing Current Model to partial View, Handling Large from Server To Clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razorengine

i want to pass All Input values of View to My Partial View(Passing User Order to Show Order Summary) but all values got null in partial View Below is My Code.

```
 <a href="#/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_@Model.CustRef" style="border-radius: 1.5rem;  margin-right:8%; margin-top: 1%; border: none;  padding:10px 2%; background: #0062cc; color: #fff; font-weight: 600; width:20%; cursor: pointer; text-align:center; font-weight:bolder;"> Submit</a>

<div id="myModal_@Model.CustRef" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="position:absolute; left:10%;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:80vw;">
            <div class="modal-header ">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Order Summary</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...Disabled Inputs...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Create Order View

```
 <form asp-action="Create">
      ....
      @*<partial name="~/Views/Order/OrderSummary.cshtml" model="Model" />*@
      @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Order/OrderSummary.cshtml", new OrderViewModel() { cus_name = Model.cus_name, cus_phone = Model.cus_phone, CustRef = Model.CustRef, Phoneid = Model.Phoneid, modelId = Model.modelId, Quantity = Model.Quantity, Address = Model.Address, CityId = Model.CityId, Date = Model.Date, store_id = Model.store_id })

    </form>
```

> **Second Question**

My Second Question is i have large data to pass to View(Admin Dashboard) to Complete Statistics but its taking too much time. Please tell me any other Efficient way to increase performance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the current input model to the controller through `ajax` and return 
to render the new partial view.

Please refer to the following code:

Controller:

```
 public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            OrderViewModel orderView = new OrderViewModel();
            return View(orderView);
        }
        public PartialViewResult ShowParitalView(OrderViewModel orderView)
        {
            return  PartialView("OrderSummary", orderView);
        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
@using WebApplication_core_mvc.Models;
@model OrderViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}  
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("a").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("div .modal").attr("id", "myModal_" + $("#cus_name").val());
                $("a").attr("data-target", "#myModal_" + $("#cus_name").val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Order/ShowParitalView",
                    data: $("form").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#partial').html(data);
                        $("#myModal_" + $("#cus_name").val()).modal('show');
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
}
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="cus_name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="cus_name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="cus_name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="cus_phone" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="cus_phone" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="cus_phone" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CustRef" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CustRef" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CustRef" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Phoneid" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Phoneid" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Phoneid" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="modelId" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="modelId" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="modelId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CityId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="store_id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="store_id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="store_id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>


    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_@Model.CustRef"
       style="border-radius: 1.5rem;  margin-right:8%; margin-top: 1%; border: none;
padding:10px 2%; background: #0062cc; color: #fff; font-weight: 600; width:20%;
cursor: pointer; text-align:center; font-weight:bolder;">
        Submit
    </a>
    <div id="myModal_@Model.CustRef" class="modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="position:absolute; left:10%;">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" style="width:80vw;">
                <div class="modal-header ">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Order Summary</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="partial">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

</form>
```

OrderSummary Partial View:

```
@using WebApplication_core_mvc.Models;
@model OrderViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="cus_name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="cus_name" class="form-control"  disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="cus_phone" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="cus_phone" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CustRef" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="CustRef" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Phoneid" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Phoneid" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="modelId" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="modelId" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="store_id" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="store_id" class="form-control" disabled/> 
</div>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

For the second question, there are too many SQL query statements in your code, you can try to improve performance by referring to [this](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/5-entity-framework-performance-tips-KX).

Comment: Thank you for Your Answer. however i have another question since i am using many selects in my order form which give me value(PhoneID,modelId,StoreId etc) but i want to show text of these selects not id. is there any way to get both value and text field with select or i need to find text Values based on Id from Db.

Comment: @MuhammadSami, Since you did not provide your current code, I don’t know how you bind the data source. When you create the select data source in the code behind, you can bind the corresponding value you want to display to the `Text ` field of  `SelectListItem `,the id is bound to the `Value` field, you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835452/displaying-data-in-a-selectlist-in-asp-net-core

Comment: can u help me in this also?                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613021/receivemessage-event-not-calling-signalr