# Select Tag Helper renders an empty list when getting data from viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get the select tag helper to list items from my view model property but it is always empty when I rendered on the browser:

The view model has:

```
public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> AssetTypes { get; set; }
```

My controller has this:

```
    [HttpGet("details/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
    {

        var asset = await _assetRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
        var vm = _mapper.Map<Asset, AssetViewModel>(asset);            
        var assetTypes = await _assetTypeRepository.ListAsync();
        vm.AssetTypes = assetTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.AssetTypeName
        }).ToList();            

        return View(vm);
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on the last line, I see the 3 items in the AssetTypes property.

My view has:

```
<select id="AssetTypeId" asp-for="AssetTypeId" asp-items="@Model.AssetTypes">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

Even when I put a breakpoint on this line in my view, I again see the 3 items that should appear. But when viewing in the browser, the select tag gets rendered as:

```
<select id="AssetTypeId" asp-for="0" asp-items="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem]">
     <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

Clearly the rendered HTML tells me why my list is empty but I don't know how to fix this. I tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc) but keep getting the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag helper is not triggering at all.

In your `ViewImports.cshtml` file, are you including the appropriate tag helpers? E.g:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: That was it. My project did not have such a file so I added it in the Views folder and that did the trick.