# Populating MVC model properties with an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Following `Post method` in my `ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1` app adds a record to database. The method successfully adds the record as long as user selects `exactly` 3 order types from a `multi-select dropdown`. User is supposed to select `at most` 3 order types from the dropdown. So, if a user selects less than 3 order types it, as expected, throws the well-know error: `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. **Question**: How can I avoid the above error if user selects `less than 3` order types. I guess I can place the entire `var oOrder = new Order{...}` statement below inside each block of an `if...else..` to avoid the error. But in real scenario there are lots more model properties and hence repeating them 3 times in `if...else...` blocks would make the code look a more complicated than it really is. Are there any better ways of doing it?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddOrder(OrderViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var oOrder = new Order
        {
            orderName = model.orderName,            
            StartDate = model.StartDate,
            EndDate = model.EndDate,
            ....
            ....
            lkupType_1_ID = model.SelectedTypeIDs[0],
            lkupType_2_ID = model.SelectedTypeIDs[1],
            lkupType_3_ID = model.SelectedTypeIDs[2],
            ....
        };

            _context.Add(oOrder);
    }
    return RedirectToAction(....);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

**snapshot of the View**

```
....
<div>....</div>
....

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SelectedOrderTypeIDs"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="SelectedOrderTypeIDs" asp-items="Model.lstOrderTypes"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="submit">Add Order</button>
```

**NOTE**: I'm using ASP.NET [MVC tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms) and often use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624217/1232087) from `@Shyju` for good example of multi-select tag helper.

Comment: How are you building your view? The default modelbinder requires unbroken indexes in the posted model, so if you aren't posting the right form values, your model won't bind correctly.

Comment: @TiesonT.I've added an UPDATE to my post to answer your question. Bare in mind that the code does `works fine for selecting 3` items from dropdown

Comment: Is this inside the tag helper for a form? Depending on how your helpers are nested, they should generate hidden form inputs if you're using the strongly-typed helpers, which will make sure that (in the case of collection-type properties) your indexes are sequential from 0.

Comment: @TiesonT.Yes it is inside tag helper for form and it is sequential from 0 - and works fine if selecting 3 items.

Comment: I'm referring the indexes on the posted data - when you get the error you're seeing, I assume it's because you're only posting something like `SelectedOrderTypeIDs[1]`. When that happens, the entire collection will not be bound. Can you post a version of the data you're actually sending?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Length` property in order to check the number of items in `SelectedTypeIDs` list.

```
if(model.SelectedTypeIDs.Length>3){
   //code
}
```

If the condition is `false` you can use `ModelState.AddModelError`  method in order to show the `error` in the **View**.

```
if(model.SelectedTypeIDs.Length>3){
   ModelState.AddModelError("Dropdown", "Error! You must have maximum of 3 options");
   return View();
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can create a `generic` function which `returns` 0, if the `index` is out of bound or the list item instead.

```
public static TValue GetSafe<TItem>(this IList<TItem> list, 
int index, TValue defaultValue)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
    {
       return defaultValue;
    }
    return list[index];
}
```

Now you can use this function to implement you functionality.

```
var oOrder = new Order
        {
            orderName = model.orderName,            
            StartDate = model.StartDate,
            EndDate = model.EndDate,
            ....
            ....
            lkupType_1_ID =model.SelectedTypeIDs.GetSafe(0, 0) ,
            lkupType_2_ID =model.SelectedTypeIDs.GetSafe(1, 0) ,
            lkupType_3_ID =model.SelectedTypeIDs.GetSafe(2, 0) ,
            ....
        };
```

Comment: But user can select `at most` 3 meaning 1,2 or 3. The condition is not exactly 3, it's rather <=3. So the error occurs if user selects only, say, 1 or 2 order types.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai That's a bit more of an extra work for my scenario. But it's a good example to keep maybe for future work that may have several such scenarios where we can just reuse your extension where ever needed. Others may also benefit from it.

Comment: Why do you not use it ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I will in other projects. But here I think I would just get by by using 3`if..else` blocks. In the current app I've only one such scenario. No reusing applies. I think your code is a good candidate when you have a scenario of my example at multiple places.

Comment: Then you have to use 3 `if..else` conditions like this: `if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, an `if` as a tenary operator:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddOrder(OrderViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var oOrder = new Order
            {
                orderName = model.orderName,            
                StartDate = model.StartDate,
                EndDate = model.EndDate,
                ....
                ....
                lkupType_1_ID = (model.SelectedTypeIDs.Length > 0) ? model.SelectedTypeIDs[0] : 0, // You can default it to null if it is Int?
                lkupType_2_ID = (model.SelectedTypeIDs.Length > 1) ? model.SelectedTypeIDs[1] : 0,
                lkupType_3_ID = (model.SelectedTypeIDs.Length > 2) ? model.SelectedTypeIDs[2] : 0,
                ....
            };

                _context.Add(oOrder);
        }
        return RedirectToAction(....);
    }
```

Comment: When I select, say, 2, it still gives the same error. I think this is because, in the `ternary operator ` we are still asking compiler to evaluate `model.SelectedTypeIDs[2]` which turns out to be out of array.