# Select Tag Helper ASP .NET CORE 2.0 is not setting selected value

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am trying to use select tag helper in ASP .NET Core 2.0 MVC application according to this thread [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc#) .

Here is my view model :

```cs
public class SensorEditViewModel
{
    public int SensorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public string AE_SN { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubscriptionEndDate { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool sensorAccessApproved { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public SelectList UserEmailList { get; set; }
}
```

Here is part of GET where model is filled with propper SelectList and UserId and pushed to the view:

```cs
var users = _context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName).Select(x => new { Text = x.Email, Value = x.Id });
model.UserEmailList = new SelectList(users, "Value", "Text");
model.Id = ownerId;

return View(model);
```

and finally in the Edit view I am using Select TagHelper like this :

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">User Email</label>
    <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@Model.UserEmailList" class="form-control" ></select>
</div>
```

But my problem is that Select is not preset with value selected in controller (model.Id = ownerId;). Do you have any clue what might be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What you mean with "is not preset with value selected in controller (model.Id = ownerId;)", actually, according to your code the Select will have "id" from the Users `new { Text = x.Email, Value = x.Id }`. What values are you getting when the html is rendered?

Comment: I mean that there is no selected value when the html is rendered. Currently rendered HTML looks like this 


`<select class="form-control" id="Id" name="Id">
     <option value="fbb907b5-2d27-470e-8ef7-fb0e3e893b3d">jdddd@ddd.sk</option>
     <option value="ad0c095e-b0a1-440d-9ed6-8c2ec52ecdc1">xxxx@xxx.com</option>
     <option value="2a829fbd-fc23-4e95-b7c5-20ec741aa70c">aaaa@gmail.com</option>
</select>`

Comment: Try changing it to `<select asp-for="UserId">` And btw your view model doesn't have an `Ìd` property.

Comment: Actually when I changed Value from Id to Email, it works well and selected option is present in HTML

Comment: To be honest, the naming of your view model's properties is a bit messed up. Cleaning it up would help solving this kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the selected value into the SelectList constructor:

`model.UserEmailList = new SelectList(users, "Value", "Text", ownerId)`

More info in the MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)