# Create DropDownListFor from List<myType>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class Nationality
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalData
{
    public List<Nationality> availableNationalities { get; set; }

    public PersonalData()
    {
        availableNationalities = new List<Nationality>();
    }
}
```

In my view, I want to create a `DropDownlistFor` using the `availableNationalities` field on the `PersonalData`.

Follows a piece of view code and an example what I'm trying to do:

```
@model PersonalData
@Html.DropDownListFor(
                    model => model.personalData.nationality,
                    new SelectList(Model.availableNationalities, "ID", "name"),
                    "Choose please an option",
                    new { required = "required" }
                )
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will throw an exception as there is no `personalData` property on your `PersonalData` view model.

Add one more property in your view model to store the selected option value

```
public class PersonalData
{
    public int SelectedNationality { set;get;}
    public List<Nationality> AvailableNationalities { get; set; }

    public PersonalData()
    {
        AvailableNationalities = new List<Nationality>();
    }
}
```

Now in your view you can use the select tag helper (in your ASP.NET Core app)

```
@model PersonalData
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create">

    <select asp-for="SelectedNationality" 
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AvailableNationalities ,"Id","Name"))">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

If it is a Non core app, you can use the `DropDownListFor` helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
                       a=> a.SelectedNationality,
                       new SelectList(Model.AvailableNationalities, "ID", "name"),
                       "Choose please an option",
                       new { required = "required" }
                    )
```

Assuming your GET action method set the `AvailableNationalities` property on your `PersonalData` viewmodel object before sending it to the view.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
   var vm=new PersonalData 
   {
     AvailableNationalities = new List<Nationality>
     {
         new Nationality { Id=1, Name="USA"},
         new Nationality { Id=2, Name="Canada"},
     }
   }; 
   return View(vm); 
}
```

If all you care about is rendering a SELECT element in the view, you may simply use a `List<SelectListItem>` instead of `List<Nationality>` as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)