# SelectList rendering with multiple = "multiple" when I don't want it to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to create a simple `SelectList` that renders as a `dropdown` for use in a Create form generated with RazorPages.  For some reason, the `SelectList` renders with `multiple="multiple"` which results in all the options being shown in a frame with a scrollbar on the side instead of a `dropdown`.  I believe the issue lies with my controller and the fact that I am trying to set both the "Text" and "Value" attributes of the `SelectListItems` with an anonymous type, as I have achieved the desired result when not setting those attributes.

A lot of this is very new to me, so if anyone has any general advice with regard to my code, I would appreciate it.

Here is my view model:

```
public class CreateFileViewModel
    {
        public SelectList EnrolleeId { get; set; }
        public SelectList GroupId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult TestCreate()
        {
            //query items for SelectLists
            var users = from u in _context.Users
                        orderby u.LastName
                        select u;

            var groups = from g in _context.Group
                         orderby g.Name
                         select g;

            // Loop through queries above and convert to collections of SelectListItems
            var enrolleeSelectListItems = from u in users
                                        select new SelectListItem()
                                        {
                                            Value = u.Id.ToString(),
                                            Text = u.LastName + ", " + u.FirstName + " " + u.MiddleName
                                        };

            var groupSelectListItems = from g in groups
                                         select new SelectListItem()
                                         {
                                             Value = g.ID.ToString(),
                                             Text = g.Name
                                         };

            //convert SelectListItem collections into SelectLists within view
            var cfvm = new Models.TestModels.CreateFileViewModel();
            cfvm.EnrolleeId = new SelectList(enrolleeSelectListItems, "Value", "Text");
            cfvm.GroupId = new SelectList(groupSelectListItems, "Value", "Text");

            return View(cfvm);
        }
```

This is the relevant portion of my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EnrolleeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="EnrolleeId" asp-items="Model.EnrolleeId">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and here is how it renders in the browser:

```
<select id="EnrolleeId" multiple="multiple" name="EnrolleeId" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="3e60fabd-6901-45a1-ae2a-5056d77f415c"></option>
                    <option value="40ce8b6e-62a5-4c3c-808b-90e36d633ec0"></option>
                    <option value="c0c49df2-da52-4a01-9a8a-47bab6f5496d"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the property you used for `asp-for` (`EnrolleeId`) is collection type. `SelectList` implements `IEnumerable`

Ideally you should have 2 properties, one for the collection of items needed to build the list of options and one for the selected option value

```
public class CreateFileViewModel
{
    public int SelectedEnrolleId {set;get;}  // This new one
    public SelectList EnrolleeId { get; set; }

    public SelectList GroupId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

And in the view

```
<select asp-for="SelectedEnrolleId" asp-items="Model.EnrolleeId">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

This will render the select element with name and id attribute values set to `SelectedEnrolleId`. So when you submit the form , that is where you should read it from.

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I suggest you rename the `SelectList` property to be something like `EnroleeList` (from EnrolleeId) which makes more sense.

Comment: Is renaming the SelectList property more for clarity or is there a naming convention or something I'm violating?

Comment: I also noticed that, you are already making a list of `SelectListItem` objects in your LINQ query(`enrolleeSelectListItems `)  and creating another `SelectList` from that. That is redundant and unnecessary. You can use `List<SelectListItem>` as the type of `EnrolleeId` property. See this post for different options [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)