# asp.net core select tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html-select, multi-select

I'm trying to follow [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc) but I am unable to get the desired results. I am able to retrieve records from the database and populate my select tags with the correct value/text for all available options but when submitting my form no values are being returned and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below. Thank you.

Model 1:

```
public class Basis
    {    
        public int BasisId { get; set; }
        public string BasisName { get; set; }
    }
```

Model 2:

```
public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Basis> Basis { get; set; }

        public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
 {
```

View:

```
<select id="basisSelect" multiple="multiple" asp-for="Basis" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Basis, "BasisId", "BasisName"))"></select>
<select id="categorySelect" asp-for="Category" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Category, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"))"></select>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitSearch(SearchManager criteriaManager)
{}
```

When I make a selection I get a count of zero. As shown in the image [image]

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: What does your controller signature look like?

Comment: I've added my controller to the original question. Thank you again.

Comment: @user1860688 try using `[FromBody]` on the post action. `SubmitSearch([FromBody]SearchManager criteriaManager)`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get an answer from another source for anyone interested or runs into a similar issue.

the select's only post back the selected value, not the list, so your post back model should be:

```
public class PostBackSearchManager
{
        public string Basis { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitSearch(PostBackSearchManager criteriaManager)
{
}

// alternate action method
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitSearch(string basis, string category)
{
}
```

Comment: if multi-select then just use an array:  public string[] Basis { get; set; }
        public string[] Category { get; set; }

Comment: yeah your searchmanager class will not give you multi select values