# C# dictionary keys to array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dictionary

I have a drop down list that enables me to select multiple items. I'm using a dictionary list to display the items. So, in order for multiple items to be selected, I need to convert the dictionary list into an array. Here is what it looks like:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> DropdownItem = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "", "" },
        { "1", "item1" },
        { "2", "item2" },
        { "3", "item3" },
        { "4", "item4" },
        { "5", "item5" },
    };

       <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DropdownItem" class="control-label" multiple></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="DropdownItem" class="text-danger"></span>
            <select asp-for="DropdownItem" class="form-control">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">drop down</option>
                <option value="1">item1</option>
                <option value="2">item2</option>
                <option value="3">item3</option>
                <option value="4">item4</option>
                <option value="5">item5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

This is what it looks like when I've converted it into an array:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> DropdownItem = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
    {
        { "", "" },
        { "1", "item1" },
        { "2", "item2" },
        { "3", "item3" },
        { "4", "item4" },
        { "5", "item5" },
    };
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The "before" and the "after" are identical. Also, what do you mean by "being correct"?

Comment: Your value in the second is a string array but you're passing in just normal strings.

Comment: Also this code won't even compile your dictionary is of type <string,string[]> and you are populating it with <string,string> pairs

Comment: Yeah I have zero idea what you are asking.  Using the Select Tag helper is trivial when you have an `IEnumerable<>` of something.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc), your Dictionary is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` so just make the key/value: `Key` and `Value`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How should I approach this? What is the correct way?

Comment: Why dont you use a `ListBox` if you want a `DropDownList` which enables you to select multiple items?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I'm pretty new at this. Is there a better way to do this? How would this Listbox look like? Could you share a code example?

Comment: @ChrisH.: you find many tutorials in the web about ASP.NET controls

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-2.0) so you should just be able to do:

```
/*
    This assumes that you have your Dictionary<string, string> DropdownItem 
    in your @model 
*/
<select asp-for="DropdownItem" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DropdownItem,"Value","Key"))">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

There should be no need or reason to turn your `Dictionary<string, string>` into a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`.

Comment: @maccetura. I really thank you for that example. I'll follow that link and learn more about it. Best regards!