# Entity set to null after selected item from SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

When creating `Employee` entity you are supposed to select `MeetingCenter`from `DropDownList`. All `MeetingCenters` show just fine in `DropDownList` with their `Names`, but when some of them is selected and `Employee` is created Meeting Center is `null`. Im using NoSQL DocumentDB database.

Controller:

```
[ActionName("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync()
{
    ViewBag.MeetingCentersList = await _meetingCenterReposiotry.GetItemsAsync();       
    return View();
}
```

Create View:

```
@model Employee
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    { 
    ...   
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(MeetingCenter => Model.MeetingCenter, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(MeetingCenter => Model.MeetingCenter, new SelectList(ViewBag.MeetingCentersList, "MeetingCenterId", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    ...
    }
```

Piece of `Employee` Model

```
public class Employee
    {
        ... 
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "meetingCenter")]
        public MeetingCenter MeetingCenter { get; set; }
        ...
     }
```

Piece of `MeetingCenter` Model

```
public class MeetingCenter
    {
        ...
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string MeetingCenterId { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You are attempting to get `MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId` when your View is passing only `MeetingCenterId`  so it obviously doesn't work. You need to either add a `MeetingCenterId` or use `DropDownList("MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId"...` instead of `DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code, the `DropDownListFor` helper will render a SELECT element with options, which has the `MeetingCenterId` as the value attribute and the `Name` as the Text. The SELECT element's **name attribute value** will be `MeetingCenter`. So when the form is submitted the form data will look like this

```
MeetingCenter: 2
```

Assuming user selected the option with value "2".

But the `MeetingCenter` property of your view model(`Employee`) is not a numeric type, it is a complex type(`MeetingCenter`). So model binder cannot map this value to `MeetingCenter` property of your view model.

You can render the SELECT element with the name `MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId` and then model binder will be able to map the posted form data as the input element name matches with the naming-structure of your view model.

So you should render something like this inside your form.

```
<select  name="MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId">    
</select>
```

You can generate the above markup by using the SELECT tag helper and specifying `MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId` as the `asp-for` property.

```
<select asp-for="MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.MeetingCentersList, 
                                        "MeetingCenterId", "Title"))">

</select>
```

Now when the form is submitted, it will populate the `MeetingCenter` property of your view model and it's `MeetingCenterId` property.

If you want the full `MeetingCenter` property to be populated (properties other than `MeetingCenterId`, get the full object by querying the data provided by `_meetingCenterReposiotry.GetItemsAsync()` using the MeetingCenterId available to you in the HttpPost action. Something like this

```
var id = viewModel.MeetingCenter.MeetingCenterId;
var items = await _meetingCenterReposiotry.GetItemsAsync();
var item = items.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.MeetingCenterId==id);
// User item now 
// May be do somethig like : viewModel.MeetingCenter = item;
```

I also suggest you to use the correct types. If `MeetingCenterId` is numeric value, use `int` as type instead of `string`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Im using NoSQL database (JSON key - value) where IDs are supposed to be `strings`. Using that select tag helper is giving `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: items.` I would like to pass whole `MeetingCenter` to HttpPost action based on selected item.So far I still have no luck achieving it despite your advice. Could you please edit your answer and be more specific how to do that in my case ?

Comment: If you are getting that exception, make sure `ViewBag.MeetingCentersList` is a valid collection. You cannot pass entire MeetingCenter object via a form submission because your option value can have only a scalar value.In that case, try what i mentioned in the last part, which is, reading the existing object based on the selected id submitted from your form submission.

Comment: Also take a look at [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc/34624217#34624217)

Comment: I managed to get it work. Just had to populate `SelecList` with `MeetingCenterId` in controller get action and pass it via `Viewbag` to my view. Your link guide helped, nice job.