# How do I populate a DropDown List using Razor Pages with No Controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am stuck on this one part. When I do a search all that comes up is examples with controllers, viewbags and other examples in MVC.

I am trying to populate a dropdown list from a database. Here is my code so far

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set}
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Editor.cshtml.cs

```
public class Editor : PageModel
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public Editor(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
    {
       _context = databasecontext;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();
        categoryList = (from Category in _context.Category select Category).ToList();
        categoryList.Insert(0, new Category { CategoryID = 0, CategoryName = "Select" });
    }
}
```

What would be my next steps in attaching the dropdownlist to my Razor View Page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [select tag helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc) with razor pages as well.

Add 2 other public properties to your page model. One for the collection of items to be used to display the option items and the other for storing/passing the selected value.

```
public class Editor : PageModel
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public Editor(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
    {
       _context = databasecontext;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public int SelectedCategoryId { set; get; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CategoryItems { set; get; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        CategoryItems = _context.Category
                                .Select(a=> new SelectListItem { 
                                                     Value = a.CategoryId.ToString(), 
                                                     Text = a.CategoryName })
                               .ToList();
    }
}
```

Now in your view, use the SELECT tag helper.

```
@page
@model Editor
<form method="post">

    <select asp-for="SelectedCategoryId" asp-items="@Model.CategoryItems">
        <option>Select one</option>
    </select>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">SAve</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

When user submits the form, You can read the selected option value in the `SelectedCategoryId` property of the page model.

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    var selectedCategoryId = this.SelectedCategoryId;
    // to do : return something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.