# SelectediAlertIndex from SelectTagHelper (apparently) not passed to Index.cshtml from LoadAlert(…) …RedirectToAction(“Index”,”Alerts”)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Struggling with getting the SelectedAlertIndex (int) from AspNetCore MVC view page:

```
 @{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>
    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="LoadAlert" method="post">
        <select asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="LoadAlert" value="LoadAlert" />
    </form>
}
```

thru AlertsController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoadAlert(Alert obj, string LoadAlert)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoadAlert))
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Alert loaded successfully";
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Alerts")
}
```

to @foreach loop inside table in Views/Alerts/Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.Alert>
…
<table id="elementTable" class="smallText">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        @*@while(item.AlertIndex == item.SelectedAlertIndex)
        {*@
        <tr>
```

Without the nested @while loop, the table of rows, one for each data element, displays all three records of 13 data elements each, but what I want is to display the set of 13 data elements for the one selected record using the int value of the AlertIndex selected from the Select Tag Helper dropdownlist. If I uncomment the @while loop only the border of the “elementTable” is displayed with no rows. This also happens when I try adding a “Where” clause to the @foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(item => item.AlertIndex == item.SelectedAlertIndex))
{
```

I’m trying to only show relevant code for the problem, but just in case it’s needed here’s the basic model:

```
public class AlertViewModel
{
    public int SelectedAlertIndex { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Alert_Identifiers { get; set; }
    public List<AlertVm> Alerts { get; set; }
}

public class AlertVm
{
    [Key]
    public int AlertIndex { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Alert_Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

I decided it probably wasn’t needed to show the Alert class of 13 elements that I ended up adding to the view model, from the original Alert.cs class.

Comment: Your `LoadAlert` method is doing only the redirect. You should pass the `SelectedAlertIndex` value (selected option value) via querystring to the Index action and use that to get the data needed. But why are you submitting the form which does only redirect? Why not submit the form to the `Index` action ?

Comment: I'm still learning these things. Please excuse my ignorance. I don't know how to pass the SelectedAlertIndex via a querystring to the Index Action. Could you perhaps refer me to a Tutorial that illustrates that or how to submit the form to the `Index` action? I've done several dropdownlist/Select Tag Helper tutorials, but I'm not clear how to do this. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Change value of  `asp-action` in the form tag helper usage to `Index`. You can add a parameter with same name as your input name (`SelectedAlertIndex`) to read the selected option value.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm so darn dense. I made the first change, but I'm only guessing that I should add parameter to `Views/Alerts/Index.cshtml` as part of the `@foreach` loop? but not how `.Where` and `@while` from previous effort (see above) didn't work. I'll keep searching for a similar example..

Comment: If someone could point me to an example of adding a parameter to read the value of the selected option it would be enormously helpful. Im so close to wrapping up this portion of the project so we can move forward to provide this reference implementation of the Common Alerting Protocol (CAP). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You add the parameter to your action method, not view.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc/34624217#34624217 for how to read the submitted value in your action method.

Comment: Thank you @Shyju, I'll work on this.

Comment: Thanks Again @Shyju. I have the select tag helper working with options from database, but when the view page Index.cshtml loads, it loads all three records. Not just the one record identified by the `SelectedAlertIndex` value (which shows in the url `http://localhost:61553/Alerts#2` or #1 or #3). Adding @while, @if etc loops to the foreach loop in the table doesn't work. The table goes blank instead of showing the selected Alert from the Alert table. I'll just keep looking.

Comment: You have to do `Where` method in your GET action method to create a subset of objects which you will pass to the view.

Comment: Thanks again. Here is // GET: Alerts `public ActionResult Index(int SelectedAlertIndex) {`
`return View(_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex)); }` The result of this is standard view with an empty table, same as with @while and @if and .Where loops inside @foreach in table in Index.cshtml.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your method, debug and inspect the value of `SelectedAlertIndex` and see it  has the expected value.

Comment: Put breakpoint on return line. It doesn't have the expected the value. It's showing 0. So the value isn't being passed. Obviously I don't understand why it has that value nor how to finally fix it. If you can help chances are I'll actually learn this lesson.

Comment: So check the form elements name is matching with the parameter name. Inspect the form submit pay load (F12 -> network tab)

Comment: The form is`<form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="Index" method="post">` and `<select asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.Alert_Identifiers">` When I highlight `SelectedAlertIndex` then hit F12 the editor switches to the AlertViewModel.cs with `SelectedAlertIndex` selected. So it looks to me that SelectedAlertIndex` matches up. No?

Comment: With the code you shared, it should work fine.

Comment: I shutdown the computer and let it rest for half an hour, then rebooted and opened up the Visual Studio Project and ran it, but it resulted in the empty table again, so I'm going to leave it shutdown overnight and see if that helps.

Comment: I do no think that is going to work :)

Comment: @Shyju Thanks so much! I appreciate you taking the time to look into this. I didn't really think shutting down overnight was going to work. I'm just stumped. Funny thing: I had the same problem with this project in NetBeans/Java last year before I switched to Visual Studio/C#. With all this stuff, there just has to be a pony (somewhere) ;)

Comment: @Shyju, Eureka! I got the bleeping thing to work!! by making sure that `SelectedAlertIndex` was an int everywhere and only pushing it `ToString` to evaluate `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedAlertIndex.ToString()))` in HttpPost Index() action. Thanks so much again for your help. Now that I have the pattern I can use it in all the data categories. Hurray!!!

Comment: Glad to know you figured it out. BTW, Instead of using ToString() and then IsNullOrEmpty, consider using nullable int (`int?`) and do a null check. Always use the correct types.

Comment: Sounds like a very good idea. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change value of asp-action in the form tag helper usage to Index:

```
@{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>

    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="Index" method="post">
        <select asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Index" value="LoadAlert" />
    </form>
}
```

Then I needed to make sure that `SelectedAlertIndex` was spelled the same in all instances; changed its type to Nullable int (`int?`); put a null check in the HttpPost Index() action; and add a `Where` condition:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Alert obj, int? SelectedAlertIndex)
    {
        if (SelectedAlertIndex.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Alert loaded successfully";
        }
        return View(_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));
    }
```

Many Thanks to @Shyju