# How to use a select dropdown for DateTime-field and maintain MVC model binding?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Asp.Net Core MVC scaffolding has given me this HTML for inputing a `DateTime`-field:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="ShiftStarts" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="ShiftStarts" class="form-control" />
  <span asp-validation-for="ShiftStarts" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

... which is fine, but I really only care about the time, not the date, and I want to replace it with a dropdown with only a selection of preset times (e.g. 06:00, 06:15, 06:30, etc.).

I imagine I have to do something like this:

```
<select asp-for="ShiftStarts" class="form-control">
    <option disabled value="0">- choose a time -</option>
    @for (int hh = 0; hh < 24; hh++)
    {
        for (int mm = 0; mm < 4; mm++)
        {
            int m = mm * 15;
            <option value="/* what goes here? */">
                @hh.ToString("D2"):@m.ToString("D2")
            </option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

How can I achieve this and have model binding work as well?

Comment: Why not use the SELECT tag helper ? [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not generate option lists manually inside view page like that. Try using a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property inside viewmodel class which returns list of times based on preset interval as in example below:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfTimeIntervals 
{ 
    get 
    {
       var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
       // range of hours, multiplied by 4 (e.g. 24 hours = 96)
       int timeRange = 96;

       // range of minutes, e.g. 15 min
       int minuteRange = 15;

       // starting time, e.g. 0:00
       TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);       

       // placeholder
       list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Choose a time", Value = "0", Disabled = true }); 

       // get standard ticks
       DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks); 

       // create time format based on range above
       for (int i = 0; i < timeRange; i++)
       {
           int minutesAdded = minuteRange * i;
           TimeSpan timeAdded = new TimeSpan(0, minutesAdded, 0);
           TimeSpan tm = startTime.Add(timeAdded);
           DateTime result = startDate + tm;

           list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = result.ToString("HH:mm"), Value = result.ToString("HH:mm") });          
       }

       return list;
   }                                
}
```

Then set `asp-items` attribute to obtain the option list:

```
<select asp-for="ShiftStarts" asp-items="Model.ListOfTimeIntervals" class="form-control">
</select>
```

An example for time interval selection can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DNhWr2).

Comment: I'll test that out tomorrow! :)