# c# Razor Pages Select Tag Helper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, razor

New to Razor, c# and ASP and with refrence to the following. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Currently I'm able to arrange my rows from my model into a select view using the following code in my Pages code.

```
public SelectList Ratings { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {

        IQueryable<string> ratingQuery = from m in _context.Ratings
                                         orderby m.MovieRating
                                         select m.MovieRating;

        Ratings = new SelectList(await ratingQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());


        return Page();

    }
```

And within my HTML page reference that to produce a nice list of ratings to choose from.

```
<select asp-for="Movie.Rating" asp-items="Model.Ratings">
            </select>
```

My issue is the options generated do not have a value other than that of the Movie.Rating field (i.e. GOOD, BAD, UGLY), everything works ok but when I inset into the DB I would like to inset the "ID" and not the "MovieRating"

I would like to have the following html created when the page is generated. Where the ID field from within the Table is the Value and the "MovieRating" is the Text.

```
<select asp-for="Movie.Rating" asp-items="Model.Ratings">
  <option value="1">Good</option>
  <option value="2">Bad</option>
  <option value="3">Ugly</option>
</select>
```

In order to do this I know I need to select more than the "MovieRating" field within the select statement. So I can change this to also select the ID. However it will just spit out a combined string into the option field and not produce a value field.

Is this the correct method to achieve what I want to do. I can find a few examples online of how to achieve this another way but I do not want to delve into MVC just yet.

Comment: Change your query so it gets the name and the id: `var ratingQuery = ...select new { m.MovieRating, m.MovieId }` and learn how to create a SelectList from that. There are plenty of examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current LINQ query is **SELECT**ing a single column, `MovieRating` and you are using the result of executing that query, which is a list of strings, to build the `SelectList` object. Your select tag helper is using this `SelectList` object which has only the MovieRating string values as the underlying items.

Assuming your `Ratings` class has an `Id` property(`int` type) and `MovieRating` property(`string` type), you may create a `SelectListItem` in the projection part of your LINQ expression.

```
List<SelectListItem> ratingItems = _context.Ratings
                                            .Select(a=>new SelectListItem
                                                       {
                                                          Value=a.Id.ToString(),
                                                          Text = a.MovieRating
                                                       }).ToList();

Ratings = ratingItems;
return Page();
```

Here the `ratingItems` is a list of `SelectListItem` objects. So change your `Ratings` properties type to a collection of `SelectListItem` objects.

```
public List<SelectListItem> Ratings { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have changed my code and this is now working. Quick question, why do/should we convert the ID to string ?

Comment: Use the correct type. If you are storing numeric values, use `int`

Comment: Take a look at [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)  for various options to use the select tag helper