# When Create in CRUD show other column then Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Pretty sure you guys will know that i'm
fairly new in this by looking at my problem.
So when i create From CRUD i get foreign key id values which is understandable here my foreign key is Grade id but i want to show user not id but grade which can be A,B,C which is stored in another Column while still saving foreign key ID when user click on create
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv3xT.png)
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: In the View Itself use the grade "text" in the drop-down instead of the id. The Id will be the value of the drop-down when sending back to the server. Check out how it works in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541948/2689390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the display of the dropdownlist is the Grade value rather than Grade id , you could try Using **ViewBag** to transfer the list of items

```
 public IActionResult Create()
    {
        //using viewbag
        ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(_context.Country, "Id", "CountryName");
        return View();
    }
```

And in the view

```
<select asp-for="CountryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Country"></select>
```

More methods of  Select Tag Helper binding value, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624217/10201850)

Comment: This method worked but by using ViewData Thanks a lot. :)