# SelectList dropdown list showing multiple = "multiple" for current viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

This kind of a bizarre issue and I can't figure out a solution how I want. 
I'm using .net core 2.1. I have a orders view model like this:

```
public class OrdersFilterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Account Numbers:")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

My viewmodel and `SelectList` in my orders controller is called like this:

```
var vm = new OrdersFilterViewModel
{
    AccountNumbers = new SelectList(_context.Account.Where(m => m.UserID == userId), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account)
};

return PartialView("_FilterOrders", vm);
```

The problem lies when trying to get a dropdown list in the view which looks like this:

```
<form asp-action="FilterOrders" asp-controller="Order" id="ordersFilterForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="AccountNumbers" class="control-label"></label>
       <select asp-for="AccountNumbers" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AccountNumbers">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This somewhat works but gives me a textarea type display where `multiple = "multiple"` is always tacked on in the browser. I've discovered that if I add something like the following to my viewmodel:

```
public int? AccountId { get; set; }
```

Then change my view to:

```
<select asp-for="AccountId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AccountNumbers">
```

I can then have my dropdown list. However, I don't need that property for anything as far as I know. I tried a million things so it's possible I made some other slight changes I'm forgetting to get that to work, but that's the gist of it.

Is there any way around adding that extra property? Or do I need it for something I'm not aware of? Or is there any way to set `multiple = "false"` or something to that effect so I can get my dropdown list with my original viewmodel and such?

I haven't dealt with the `post` back to the controller yet, so maybe that will reveal the gotchas. I'm basically trying to create a modal type query filter that doesn't really do much other than modify some parameters and send them back to my query to update it. Thanks.

Comment: Share us the code for `FilterOrders`. What do you want to send from client and what do you want to receive from controller?

Comment: @TaoZhou I don't have the code for the `FiltersOrders post` method yet. But, basically I just want a single value from each `selectlist` dropdown (e.g. account number) or nothing (if the dropdown is left blank) to get to the controller and then reform the url (querystring) to feed it back to the original query and therefore filter the results. I'm definitely open to other better ways... but, eventually I would like the queries to be saved and querystring seems the most effective way?

Comment: Do you want the accountnuber collection or userId?

Comment: @TaoZhou Neither, right now, I simply want a single account number passed back to the controller from a dropdown list, not a multi-selector box. The userId is only to make sure the user is accessing their own accounts and I grab that info in the controller with `string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way around adding that extra property? Or do I need it
>   for something I'm not aware of?

Yes, you need this extra property, because in your select there are many items, and the user will select one or multiple items, and on the server side you'll need to know what the user selected, this is the purpose of the select tag.

And the `multiple = "multiple"` depends on what you put in the `asp-for` in the case of `asp-for="AccountId"` it is a single int value, so it won't use multiple, is you have an array in the `asp-for` then it will use the multiple.

Here is a pretty detailed description about the select tag helper:
[Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: Thanks, I spent days on that page you referenced (and even upvoted it). Seems there should be some control over the UI since choosing only one option is a possibility (and otherwise, works just fine as far as I can tell with the multiple = "multiple" option that gets defaulted to). I wonder if I could override it with CSS or something since the value is what I need and not the id...

Comment: The value will be stored in the AccountId variable, you don't have to override anything.

Comment: Thanks for you comments... Unless I'm misunderstanding, the AccountId variable will store the AccountId value... (I can actually see it when debugging, but that may be because my current AccountIds in my table are 1 and 2) So my table has an AccountId, and AccountNumber columns (and maybe one other column like UserId). Is the AccountId in my table not related to the AccountId in my ViewModel? I really don't need the AccountId value, hence overriding the UI with the CSS comment.

Comment: You can set what are the texts and values in your SelectList. In your example you use this: AccountNumbers = new SelectList(_context.Account.Where(m => m.UserID == userId), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account) it means that you are using "AccountNumber" field from the DB, and you're not using AccountId, if you want to use that you should use this:  AccountNumbers = new SelectList(_context.Account.Where(m => m.UserID == userId), "AccountId", "AccountNumber", account) And the AccountId in your ViewModel will have the value what the users selected.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did before, I just forgot to put that in above as I don't think it would work otherwise. I figured out a solution based on your solution and that same premise though. Instead of using AccountId, I used just AccountNumber and then assigned that variable the selected value (from previous queries). The ViewModel then posts back and everything and I don't need to carry that AccountId around. I'm not sure if there are any gotchas (like if the selected value is empty or null), but for now it's working as I would like. Thanks for your help!