# Error when Razor page opens and have a related drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to create a form (Books) with a simple drop down list displaying fields from a related table (Authors).

Book Model:

```
namespace SimpleDropDownList.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "Book Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
        public AuthorViewModel AuthorViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Author Model:

```
namespace SimpleDropDownList.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        [Key]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace SimpleDropDownList.Models
{
    [NotMapped]
    public class AuthorViewModel
    {
        //Property to hold the list of authors in the GET
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AuthorOptions { get; set; }

        //Property to bind the selected author used in the POST
        public List<int> SelectedAuthorIds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Create() method on the BooksController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
            {
                //ViewData["AuthorID"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Author>(), "AuthorID", "AuthorID");
                AuthorViewModel vm = new AuthorViewModel();
                vm.AuthorOptions = _context.Book.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                { Value = x.AuthorID.ToString(), Text = x.Author.LastName }).ToList();
            return View(vm);
            }
```

Create View:

```html
    @model SimpleDropDownList.Models.Book

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    }

    <h1>Create</h1>

    <h4>Book</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="AuthorID" class="control-label"></label>
                    @*<select asp-for="AuthorID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AuthorID"></select>*@

                    <select asp-for="@Model.AuthorViewModel.SelectedAuthorIds" asp-items="@Model.AuthorViewModel.AuthorOptions"></select>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
    Model: AuthorViewModel
```

When the Create button is clicked the following error is generated.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'SimpleDropDownList.Models.AuthorViewModel', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'SimpleDropDownList.Models.Book'.

My expectations are simple...open the create Book form and drop down list to display the author ID and last name.

Comment: Your method create passes authorviewodel but your view expects SimpleDropDownList.Models.Book

Comment: Ric, hi. I tried changing this already. In the Create view changed the model:
    From: model SimpleDropDownList.Models.Book
    To: model SimpleDropDownList.Models.AuthorViewModel
The problem now is that the Title and AuthorID are bound to Book model so create errors.
BeginnerTejas also suggested this change in the answer below.

Comment: What is the relationship between book and author? For `public int AuthorID { get; set; }`, it seems to be one-to-one. For `AuthorViewModel`, it seems to be one-to-many. Will you select one author or many authors in the book create form?

Comment: Book-to-Author: Many-to-One.

Answer (score 0):

Change your View at the top from @model `SimpleDropDownList.Models.Book` to @model `SimpleDropDownList.Models.AuthorViewModel`

Comment: Are you getting an error in ```<select asp-for="@Model.AuthorViewModel.SelectedAuthorIds" asp-items="@Model.AuthorViewModel.AuthorOptions"></select>``` this line or on the page load itself? And please post the error after changing your model in create page if the error is a different from previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Now have this working. Moved the property from the Book class to the AuthorViewModel class. Now Looks like the below.

Book Model:

```
namespace SimpleDropDownList.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "Book Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
        // Removed this link and added property to AuthorViewModel class
        // public AuthorViewModel AuthorViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Author Model:

```
namespace SimpleDropDownList.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        [Key]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace SimpleDropDownList.Models
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public class AuthorViewModel
        {
            //Property to hold the list of authors in the GET
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AuthorOptions { get; set; }

            //Property to bind the selected author used in the POST
            public List<int> SelectedAuthorIds { get; set; }

            // Added this property to link back to Book class
            public Book Book { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Changed Create view to:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    // The ViewData line auto created by the scaffolding process
    // ViewData["AuthorID"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Author>(), "AuthorID", "AuthorID");

    AuthorViewModel vm = new AuthorViewModel();
    vm.AuthorOptions = _context.Book.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    { Value = x.AuthorID.ToString(), Text = x.Author.LastName }).ToList();

    return View(vm);
}
```