# Bind Asp.Net SelectList to parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an object Individual Action which contains a Quarter Attribute and an enum

```
public int QuarterId { get; set; }

        public QuarterList Quarter { get; set; }



        public enum QuarterList
        {
            [Display(Name = "Quarter One")]
            Q1 = 1,
            [Display(Name = "Quarter Two")]
            Q2 = 2,
            [Display(Name = "Quarter Three")]
            Q3 = 3,
            [Display(Name = "Quarter Four")]
            Q4 = 4,
        }
```

I have a CREATE route for this object in my controller which passes an object (PerformanceManagementRecord) and a int parameter(quarter)

```
 // GET: Objectives/Create
        public IActionResult Create(PerformanceManagementRecord performanceManagementProcess, int quarter)
        {
            ViewBag.PerformanceManagementProcessId = performanceManagementProcess.Id;
            ViewBag.QuarterId = quarter;
            ViewBag.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            PopulateStrategicActionDropDownList();
            return View();

        }
```

I then have a select list in my view which represents an enum list of quarters

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Quarter" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="QuarterId" class="form-control"

                            asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<IndividualAction.QuarterList>()" ></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Quarter" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

How can I bind the select list to the quarter value parameter- the URL to that create method contains the value I want to set (in this case 3)

```
https://localhost:5001/IndividualActions/Create/12?quarter=3
```

but the value defaults to the first quarter

Answer (score 0):

The solution as outlined in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc) which gives a great overview of select lists in ASP.NET is to use a View Model and not Viewbag

```
   public IActionResult Create(PerformanceManagementRecord performanceManagementProcess, int quarter)
    {


        var vm = new IndividualAction();
        vm.Quarter = new IndividualAction.QuarterList();
        vm.QuarterId = quarter;

        vm.PerformanceManagementProcessId = performanceManagementProcess.Id;
        vm.QuarterId = quarter;
        PopulateStrategicActionDropDownList();
        return View(vm);

    }
```