# Pass select items from database to modal using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

I have a basic modal that i need to pass some select options to. I retrieve them from the database with a service method.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNote()
        {
            var model = new CreateNoteViewModel();
            var categories = await this.categoryService.GetAllCategoriesAsync();
            model.CategoryList = categories.Select(t => new SelectListItem(t.Name, t.Name)).ToList();

            return this.View(model);
        }
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="noteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="noteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="noteModalLabel">Creating a note...</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="send-feedback-form" asp-action="CreateNote" asp-controller="Management" asp-area="Management">
                    <input type="hidden" name="businessId" value="..." />
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 name">
                            <input required type="text" name="authorName" class="form-control col-form-label" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Name'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control mb-10" rows="5" name="comment" placeholder="Text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Text'"
                                  required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="department">Select Department</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="department">
                            <option>Option1</option>
                            <option>Option2</option>
                            <option>Option3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnSave">Create Note</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lets say I retrieved items: TODO, Fix, Purchase, is there a way to add them as select options to the modal with ajax?

Comment: How do you call the CreateNote method ? What does the `#createNoteButton` represent ? About rendering the select element , you could refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624217/10201850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a client accessible file that would run the `CreateNote` function you mentioned. This would be written in some sort of server side language like PHP or something of that sort and return a JSON object ideally. Then run your AJAX call with `$.getJSON()`

Should look something like this:

```
$.getJSON('myFile.php', processReturn);

function processReturn(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        $("#department").append("<option>" + val + "</option>");
    });
}
```

This may need some modification depending on the format of your data or how you call your server, but it should be something along those lines.

Comment: Couldnt that happen through ASP.NET Core Controller?

Comment: I got ASP.NET Controller to return JSON, however, I am unable to getthe ajax function you have provided to work.

Comment: Sorry there was a syntax error where I was missing a `$`. Try again and if it doesn't work I can dig deeper.

Comment: Added a new comment with a few details, cant seem to make the styling here.

Comment: When I click the button, the event is fired, however, the select options are not being changed. Check above, for the button event.

Comment: You are missing the `$.get()` command. It must be called pointing to a server script to get the JSON. Then its callback should be the function you have.

Comment: Thanks, I used .getJson and figured it out. +1

Comment: Apologies, work has kept me rather busy today. Glad to hear you got it working. I edited my answer to better fit your needs. Would you be able to accept it for people finding this question in the future?

Comment: Yes, I have accepted it, thanks for the help buddy!