# SelectListItem showing name of class not text field

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am creating a SelectList with SelectItems. The Text field is getting to the page but the Text property is not being populated with the Text instead it is using the class name, I can not figure out what I could be doing wrong.

I have found where there is a situation where there should not be a separate close for the  tag () but rather />. This made the select list empty.

This is the code in the controller (as I have said the value does get passed to the page when I am debugging)

```cs
var vitualOfficeManagerViewModel = new VirtualOfficeManagerViewModel();

var enumForSelectList = _context.BusinessType.AsEnumerable().Select(b = >new {
    b.Name,
    b.Id
});

var initalizeSelectListToAddTo = new List < SelectListItem > ();
foreach(var item in enumForSelectList) {
    var x = new SelectListItem(item.Name.ToString(), item.Id.ToString());
    initalizeSelectListToAddTo.Add(x);
}
vitualOfficeManagerViewModel.BusinessTypesSelect = new SelectList(initalizeSelectListToAddTo);

//var testt = new SelectList()
return View(vitualOfficeManagerViewModel);
```

And this is the code I have in the cshtml

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select asp-for="BusinessTypes"
            asp-items="Model.BusinessTypesSelect">
    </select>
</div>
```

I expect the list to have the value of the Text property such as "Computer Programing"

but the result is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624217/5233410

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix it with an `@`:

```
asp-items="@Model.BusinessTypesSelect">
```

This dereferences it, passing in the actual value, instead of the property itself.

Also, FWIW, you're doing a lot of useless changes to your data. Your entire action can be condensed down to:

```
var vitualOfficeManagerViewModel = new VirtualOfficeManagerViewModel
{
    BusinessTypesSelect = _context.BusinessType.Select(b => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = b.Id.ToString(),
        Text = b.Name
    })
};

return View(vitualOfficeManagerViewModel);
```

You'd need to change the type of `BusinessTypesSelect` to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead of `SelectList`, which is fine. You don't need a `SelectList`, only an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Razor is just going to use the `SelectList` you're passing right now to get at the `Items` collection on it, anyways, and then create its own.

Comment: I had it much more compact and like what you showed but in trying to fix it I just complicated it. Going back to refactor. After going through the link posted above I had tried prefixing with the @ and that did not seem to work. I did have in my ViewModel that property being a SelectList, switched it to a List and that seemed to fix it. Thanks!!