# MVC View-Unable to populate list in the select drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to implement a simple *select drop-down* in *razor page*. I am not sure if I missed anything, the dropdown is not at all populating. Just for demo purpose, I used the hard-coded string values to populate the dropdown.

I have a list called posts.

```
        var posts = new List<BlogDetails>();

        posts.Add(
        new BlogDetails {
            Id = 1,
            Author = "Charles",
            Title = "Finding Charles",
            Body = "This is a great blog post",
            PostedOn = DateTime.Now
        });

     ViewBag.listOfItems = posts;
     return View();
```

In the `Index.cshtml` I am trying to populate a dropdown using this list.

```
    <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.listOfItems, "Id", "Author"))">
    <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
```

I don't know the reason and its not working.
When I actually looked the HTML generated for this dropdown I am able to see that the list is not processed at all.

Below is the HTML generated.
[image]

Can anyone please help me to figure out what did I miss?

Comment: This is actually an MVC View, not a Razor Page, which makes a difference because ViewBag is not available in Razor Pages. Your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list was not rendering because tag helpers was not enabled. Check if you add the below line in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` directly under your Views folder

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: I cannot find _ViewImports.cshtml file in my project.

Comment: @HariKrishna , _ViewImports.cshtml file should be present by default. If not, please follow this : 1.create a file named “_ViewImports.cshtml” directly under your Views folder ; 2. add the following into it: `@using MyNameSpace 
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers ` ; 3. save file and refresh.

Comment: Thanks, @chan. This worked. My issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
 var posts = new List<BlogDetails>();

    posts.Add(
    new BlogDetails {
        Id = 1,
        Author = "Charles",
        Title = "Finding Charles",
        Body = "This is a great blog post",
        PostedOn = DateTime.Now
    });

 ViewBag.listOfItems =  new SelectList(posts, "Id", "Author");
 return View();
```

Razor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.post, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listOfItems, "--Select Post--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Or you can try this

```
  <select>
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.listOfItems)
    {
      <option value="@item.Id">@item.Author<option>
    }
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kamran. It did really work. Can we do it in such a way without using tag helpers? Something like by using the HTML select tag.

Comment: @HariKrishna I have updated the answer please check

Comment: @Kamaran Instead of writing a for loop, can we do it by using **asp-items** and **asp-for**. Like i mentioned in the question.

Comment: what are the problem with these methods?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with these methods. Each of them resolved my issue. I just want to understand why **asp-items** is not working for me. I found that while creating the project `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is missed. And hence tag helpers are not enabled. So I added that file with this line `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`. Now the tag helpers are enabled and my code is working. Thanks for your effort. I got to know various ways to use a dropdown.