# Generate list based on selected option

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to create a page for admins to create new users. When these users are created they will also have a role that they are assigned, and each of those roles will have a list of associated rights. The role will be selected from a dropdownlist of roles. After the role has been selected, but before the user has been created I want the list of associated roles to be displayed on the side of the form so they can see if the rights associated with that role are what they want.

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem without reloading the entire page after selecting a role. I'm sure how to have a refresh on a div when the information changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to achieve this.

Here is a simple solution to start with. First, create an action method in your controller which accepts the roleId value and get's the rights associated with that role and return that as JSON array.

In the below example, I am simply hard coding 2 rights. You can replace this implementation with however you want to get the data(may be from a database) using the `roleId` param value.

```
public JsonResult RoleDetails(int roleId)
{
    // Hard coded data.
    // Replace with data from your db using roleId value
    var rightList = new List<string> { "Admin", "Editor" };

    return Json(rightList);
}
```

So when called with a request URL like `/Home/RoleDetails?roleId=2`, this action method will return data like this(JSON array).

```
["Admin","Editor"]
```

Now, Render your select element with the Roles as options. We shall store the path to the action method in a data attribute on the SELECT element. For example, your rendered HTML should be like this.

```
<select id="selectedRole" data-url="/Home/RoleDetails">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option value="1">Role A</option>
    <option value="2">Role B</option>
    <option value="3">Role C</option>
</select>

<div id="role-details"></div>
```

We also rendered a div to show the details.

*I am assuming you know how to render a SELECT element. If you do not, please refer*

[Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc/34624217#34624217) post

*You can use the `Url.Action` helper to generate the correct path to the `RoleDetails` action method, for example,*

```
<select id="selectedRole" data-url="@Url.Action("RoleDetails","Home")">
```

Now you can use JavaScript to listen to the change event of the SELECT element, read the selected option value, make an ajax call to the action method we created above, get the data ,which is a JSON array, and update the UI using that.

Here is a working sample using jQuery for DOM manipulations.

```
$(function () {

    // Listen to "change" event on SELECT
    $("#selectedRole").change(function () {
        //Get the value of selected option
        var roleId = $(this).val();
        var url = $(this).data("url") + "?roleId=" + roleId;

        //Make the AJAX call
        $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
            var list = "";
            // Loop through the JSON array and build HTML for a list of P tags.
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                list += "<p>" + item + "</p>";
            });
            // Update the Div content
            $("#role-details").html(list);
        }).fail(function (e) {
            $("#role-details").html("Error getting data");
            console.warn(e);
        });
    });

})
```