# Creating DropDownList and bind data using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I want to add DropDownList and Tab for my Asp.net core application.I want to bind data for each DropDownList using different stored procedure.Do i need need to create different models for each DropDownList?

Comment: You need to get a list of models for each tab accordingly.

Comment: @PhongNguyen : Okeay.How can i work with DropDownList?

Comment: @Ijasibrahim, have a look at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/binding-dropdown-list-with-database-in-asp-net-core-mvc/ for how to work with dropdown list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo that using ViewBag to transfer the list of items

1.Model

```
public class Studio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

2. stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudio]

AS
  SELECT * FROM Studios
RETURN 0

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCity]
AS
  SELECT * FROM Cities
RETURN 0

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAddress]

AS
  SELECT * FROM Addresses
RETURN 0
```

3.Controller

```
public IActionResult DropDownList()
    {
        ViewBag.Studio = new SelectList(_context.Studios.FromSql("GetStudio"), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.City = new SelectList(_context.Cities.FromSql("GetCity"), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Address = new SelectList(_context.Addresses.FromSql("GetAddress"), "Id", "Street");
        return View();
    }
```

4. View

```
    <div>
     <label>Studio</label>
     <select name="id" asp-items="@ViewBag.Studio">
        <option>Please select one</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div>
     <label>Address</label>
     <select name="id" asp-items="@ViewBag.City">
        <option>Please select one</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div>
     <label>City</label>
     <select name="id" asp-items="@ViewBag.Address">
        <option>Please select one</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

5.Result:

[image]

Reference:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

[Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: Am using Dapper as ORM  but this post helped me.