# Using SelectList to get AspNetUsers' Id from a DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

In a `Create` method, I have a field that passes the parameter `AssignedTo` to the database column which is a Foreign Key to the AspNetUsers table. I am storing a list of UserNames in a Viewbag, making them all visible in a DropDownList.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Users = userManager.Users.Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

In the view, the code is the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="AssignedTo"></label>
    @Html.DropDownList("YourDropDownList", new SelectList(ViewBag.Users))
    <select asp-items="@new SelectList(ViewBag.Users)" asp-for="AssignedTo"></select>
</div>
```

The problem here is that my `AssignedTo` gets the value of the AspNetUser `UserName`. Following an advice from a past question, I changed the select constructor to `new SelectList(Viewbag.Users, nameof(AppUser.Id), nameof(AppUser.UserName))` but that doesn't work quite well as it returns this:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Could this be because the model I am using for this view does not contain `AppUser`? How could I fix this issue?

Comment: First, always use a dedicated viewmodel class, then use `Html.DropDownListFor` (instead of `DropDownList`) to refer to a property of your viewmodel. And don't use entity-types as root viewmodels. And **never** use `ViewBag` because it is not strongly-typed.

Comment: Don't mix HTML-helpers with Tag-Helpers. Your current cshtml will render two separate `<select>` elements.

Comment: Honestly - just avoid `SelectList` entirely, IMO.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your advice. I will try to sort it out and eventually come back with an update on how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting AspNetUsers' Id from the DropDownList , you could use ViewBag like below:

```
public IActionResult CreateTask()
{
    ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(_userManager.Users, nameof(AppUser.Id), nameof(AppUser.UserName));
    return View();
}
```

Task model:

```
public class TaskModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }

    //other properties
}
```

and in the view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="AssignedTo"></label>
    <select asp-for="AssignedTo" asp-items="@ViewBag.Users"></select>
</div>
```

You could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624217/10201850) for how to populating the Select tag helper .