# Best approach for adding relatively huge amount of data into List<PostalCode> in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing .net core 2.1 web app which has no database.
I have a task which I need to perform:

**Task:
Implement all postal codes as dropdown option with tag helpers and rendering a list within.
Example of html what should I get:**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>Postal code:</label>
    <div class="select">
        <span>Postal code</span>
        <select data-required="">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.PostalCode))
            {
                <option value="@Model.PostalCode" selected>@Model.PostalCode</option>
            }
            <option>00001</option>
            <option>00002</option>
            <option>00003</option>
            <option>258745</option>
            ...so on..
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc) and I started to develop, but question is:

- If I have 10000 postal codes like KeyValue pair, should I store it in some file, or in appsettings.json?
  Or just to do AddRange() method base on my List?

Here is the sample model of PostalCode

```
public class PostalCode
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and ofc, I have a list in my main model:

```
public class MainModel
{
    // Property needed to catch selected value
    public string SelectedPostalCode {get; set; }
    public List<PostalCode> PostalCodes { get; set; }

   //...all other properties removed for clarity...
}
```

Comment: do not add... user will not choose from 10000 option

Comment: 10,000 items in a drop-down, that goes down to the client? that's a **terrible** UX idea, and negatively impacts page performance; *at best* I would suggest jquery (or similar) based auto-complete after entering a few characters, but frankly: just let the user type it in (or have the browser auto-fill it, which most will do automatically based on context clues). On the plus side, at least it isn't a slider? but: `<input ... autocomplete="postal-code">` should be all you want and do here!

Comment: @MarcGravell you are absolutely right! Can you point me to the right direction with autocomplete? You trying say to me that I need to bind that list as hidden, and then autocomplete will work?

Comment: @Stefan0309 no, I'm saying **forget about the list**; just have a regular `<input>` and have the user **type it in** (or, via `autocomplete="postal-code"`, have their browser fill it in for them)

Comment: a form field for postal code simply would not benefit from autocomplete.  If you want to help a user fill out an address form, you're better served fetching zip code from a correctly entered street address.

Comment: @AdamVincent zip codes / postal codes are much shorter; the usual approach is to fetch a street address from a zip code, at least that's how it works in many countries; maybe US zip codes are different...

Comment: @MarcGravell no. That would assume the users address is already stored somewhere, and why even make them fill out the zip code to fetch it at that point?

Comment: The user's address *is* stored somewhere; look at all the mapping services. That said, in the interests of MVP and Principle of Least Surprise, a field works just fine.

Comment: you're telling me if I'm a new user and head over to Amazon to buy a book that I should be able to fill out the zip code field and some API is called and my exact address is filled out for me?

Comment: @AdamVincent "and why even make them fill out the zip code to fetch it at that point" - typically, the browser will do that *automatically*, but even if it didn't: why make them fill out the longer, more complex and error-prone full address instead? that just compounds the problem

Comment: @AdamVincent yes, at least that's how it works in most countries; I'm currently in the UK, and most sites will only ever ask me for 2 things: post code (think: zip code) and house number. Once those two things are entered, most sites then do an ajax query and auto-populate the rest of the address for the user to confirm

Comment: I only see that Adam soluion with API resolving is focused, if I enter the address, then  API is triggered, and return zip code, right?

Comment: @MarcGravell there, you said it. zip code AND house number. That makes sense, not just a zip code. That is your equivalent of entering an exact street address in the US.