# Select tag helper from database ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Ok, I'm trying to do a proper dropdown in Core 3.1. In this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-select-tag-helper 
Model has a new list with hardcoded values

```
public string Country { get; set; }

public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
{
   new SelectListItem { Value = "MX", Text = "Mexico" },
   new SelectListItem { Value = "CA", Text = "Canada" },
   new SelectListItem { Value = "US", Text = "USA"  },
};
```

I looked for examples where the list is coming from the database but they are very inconsistent. The only way I was able to do the dropdown list is with the ViewBag which is not advised.

I have two models. 1.

```
 public partial class Glossary
    {
        public int UniqueId { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    }
```

2. which is my view model

```
 public partial class AdminUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserLocation { get; set; }
        public string UserStatus { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<Glossary> Glossary { get; set; } //I used this for ViewBag 
        public List<SelectListItem> UserLocations { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
           according to the example my query should go here
        };      
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
           // This is the ViewBag that worked with HTML helpers, but I'm trying to use tag-helpers.
            /*IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LocationsList = _context.Glossary.Where(x => x.Category == 1).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.UniqueId.ToString(),
                Text = x.DisplayText
            });
            ViewBag.LocationsList = LocationsList;
           */
            return View();
        }
```

All examples that found were hardcoded lists and nothing with getting it from the database. What is the proper way to get the data from the Glossary table through the view model with ViewBag? Any pointers are appreciated.

ALSO:
When using this example: [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)
When I used

```
public SelectList Employees { set; get; }
```

I got error: InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'SelectListGroup' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

Both of my tables have PK and adding [Key] to Glossary model didn't fix it.

Comment: Close. You should pass data, like what you get from the context, but without the SelectListItem stuff. That you only add on the view.

Comment: @RicardoPeres So I should pass the data in the model? How can I do it if my _context is in Controller? This is still quite new to me.

Comment: Model or ViewBag, both are fine. Then have some code in a @functions block that picks up this data and builds the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

Comment: @RicardoPeres This is where I'm stuck, how can I pass this data in Model?

Comment: Pass it through the ViewBag instead, it's easier.

Comment: To achieve your requirement, as @RicardoPeres mentioned, using Model or ViewBag, both are fine. If you'd like to got a sample code, please check my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to retrieve data from db and populate a dropdown with retrieved data through a view model (or ViewBag), you can refer to following code snippet.

*In `AdminUser` view model class, include these properties*

```
public string Selected_Glossary { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> Glossary_List { get; set; }
```

*In controller*

```
public IActionResult Create(AdminUser model)
{
    var adminuser_model = new AdminUser
    {
        UserName="test"
        //for other properties
    };

    //retrieve data from Glossary table

    var items = _context.Glossary.Where(x => x.Category == 1).Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.UniqueId.ToString(),
        Text = x.DisplayText
    }).ToList();


    //pass dropdown items through a view model
    adminuser_model.Glossary_List = items;

    ////pass dropdown items through ViewBag
    //ViewBag.Glossary_List = items;

    return View(adminuser_model);
}
```

*In view page*

```
@model AdminUser

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <select asp-for="Selected_Glossary" asp-items="Model.Glossary_List"></select>
    @*populate it through ViewBag*@
    @*<select asp-for="Selected_Glossary" asp-items="ViewBag.Glossary_List"></select>*@
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using ViewBag – it lets me create multiple dropdowns with different values form the same table.