# Getting the list items by id using select tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list as:

```
private static List<Menu> GetMenu = new List<Menu>
{
    new Menu
    {
        MealId = 1,
        NameOfMeal = "Salad",
        Price = 12.99
    },
    new Menu
    {
        MealId = 2,
        NameOfMeal = "Fried Rice",
        Price = 14.89
    }
};
```

I am trying to get each item by id using select tag html:

```
<select>
    <option value"1">Salad</option>
    <option value"2">Fried Rice</option>    
</select>
```

Each of these items has its own price and I am trying to bind the item when the user select the meal to get the name and the price of the meal.

I need the price of the selected item to be binded with its price.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: No sir. Thank you for the reply

Comment: Is this a table in the database? a table called `menu`, a table called `meal`, and then `mealId` is a foreign key on `menu` table?

Comment: @janzen no sir. this is a class and a list.

Comment: Something like this maybe?: Menu thisMenu = GetMenu.Where(m => m.MenuId == selectvalue).Single();   Your select doesn't really look like it's bound to anything though... where's the whole form?

Comment: That seems to work but how to use this method in select tag html. I mean call it in the tag

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class MenuItemHelper
{
    public static MenuItem GetMenuItemByID(this List<MenuItem> menuItems, int id)
    {
        return menuItems.Where(mI => mI.MealId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

...

```
var menuItem = menuItems.GetMenuItemByID(1);
```

Comment: That's seemed to be reasonable. But how will I use or call this method in the select tag html?

Comment: I am not too familiar with ASP.NET. How would you usually access the select tags?