# Bind Dropdownlist with ViewBag in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to bind dropdownlist in `Create.cshtml` with `ViewBag` data from controller, but I got the error message as below:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable
> items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable
> selectedValues, string dataGroupField)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing ArgumentNullException: Value
> cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable
> items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable
> selectedValues, string dataGroupField)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items,
> string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items,
> string dataValueField, string dataTextField) CallSite.Target(Closure ,
> CallSite , Type , object , string , string )
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4<T0, T1, T2, T3,
> TRet>(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
> AspNetCore.Views_Home_Create.b__22_0() in Create.cshtml
> +

My model:

```cs
public class PolicyCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Category_id { get; set; }
    public string Category_name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<PolicyCategory> CategoryList  = new List<PolicyCategory>();
    
    var myList  = (from c in _context.PolicyCategory
                        select new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Value= c.Category_id.ToString(),
                            Text=c.Category_name
                        }).ToList();
    myList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem {Value = string.Empty, Text = "Select" });
    
    ViewBag.Category = myList;
    return View(await _context.Policy.ToListAsync());
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label"></label>
    <select name="Category" 
            asp-for="Category "class="form-control" 
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Category,"Value","Text"))">
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Category" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Where the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: don't use viewbag... just bind a list of Select... something like public List<SelectListItem> YourSelectItems;  then in your cshtml, something like: <select asp-for="Category" asp-items="Model.YourSelectItems">  (You may also want to set the value for the one you insert... so "Value = '-1'... it's possible that string.Empty is coming through as null)

Comment: I tested with your code, but on my side,there's no error.then I set the value of mylist to 0,i got the same error with you.I checked the code  asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Category,"Value","Text"),  asp-items requires List<SelectListItem>,but you suppled a SelectList

Comment: so,I think modify your codes" asp-items=ViewBag.Category" may help,althought the codes work well on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this example [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

My problem was in the modelview class, add

```
[NotMapped]
public List<PolicyCategory> Categories { get; set; }
```

in controller, add the Categories to the PolicyViewModel

```
    PolicyViewModel vm = new  PolicyViewModel();
            
    List<SelectListItem> Categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
    vm.Categories = (from c in _context.PolicyCategory
                             select c
                             ).ToList();
                            
    return View(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewbag isn't the best mode of binding data with .NET core. It is best to use a ViewModel.

1. Set the binding in the code backend.

   ```
      [BindProperty]
      public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
   ```
2. Return the Data in the Controller

   ```
   Categories = myList;

   return Page();
   ```
3. Bind the Data from ViewModel in your markup

   ```
   <select id="ddlCategories" name="Categories" asp-items="@Model.Categories">
            <option value="@Model.Value">@Model.Text</option>
        </select>
   ```

That should do

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem here is I have a PolicyCategoryViewModel which is to populate dropdownlist  and a PolicyViewModel to popluate the whole view. I need to display these two tables in my view. Right now, my view page only includes mynamespace.Models.Policy, I need to include both view Models. How do I do that in the controller? Thanks.

Comment: You can just use one ViewModel eg: PolicyViewModel and add "List<SelectListItem> Categories" property to this. Then return this PolicyViewModel to the view

Comment: I tried to add Categories as   [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> Categories  { get; set; }  to the PolicyViewModel but the view page still cannot find my Categories, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you populate the Categories in the controller and pass it to the view?

Comment: I did populate the Categories in the controller. BTW I am using .net core, does @Html.DropDownListFor() work in .net core? I need to use asp-items.

Comment: are you using RazorPages?

Comment: yes, Razor page