# How to have multiple SELECT elements in a FOR loop inside an cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, model, razor-pages

If I have a `.cshtml` file and have a `FOR` loop such as

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)
```

how do I have a `SELECT` list inside, how do I set the different `SELECTED` values

```
    Titles = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Value = "Mr", Text = "Mr"},
        new SelectListItem{ Value = "Mrs", Text = "Mrs"},
        new SelectListItem{ Value = "Miss", Text = "Miss"},
        new SelectListItem{ Value = "Dr", Text = "Dr"}
    };

    newContact.ContactId = 1;
    newContact.Title = "Mr";
    newContact.Email = "mail@mail";
    newContact.HireDate= DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)
    {
       <select name="[@i].Title" asp-items="Model.Titles"></select>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: What do you want to set your selected value based on?

Comment: If I am listing like above a list of contacts in FOR loop in the VIEW and each contact could have a different title like "Mr","Mrs" etc. I know I can set the SELECT element with asp-items="Model.Titles" but how do I set the SELECTED value for each contact. Do I need to store the List<SelectListItem> for each contact?

Answer (score 0):

Use new SelectList class with `(IEnumerable items, object selectedValue)` params, for your asp-items, like so:

```
<select name="[@i].Title" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Titles, Model.Title))"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of dropdown list is the same for each contact, So I think  contains `List<SelectListItem>` in each contact is not a good idea. I write a simple demo to show my idea, Hope it can give your some help.

**Model**

```
public class People
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
           new SelectListItem{ Value = "Mr", Text = "Mr"},
            new SelectListItem{ Value = "Mrs", Text = "Mrs"},
            new SelectListItem{ Value = "Miss", Text = "Miss"},
            new SelectListItem{ Value = "Dr", Text = "Dr"}
        };

        //For testing, I just hard code here
        List<People> people = new List<People>()
        {
            new People()
            {
                FirstName = "Bob",
                LastName = "Smith",
                Title = "Mr",
            },
            new People()
            {
                FirstName = "Sam",
                LastName = "Perry",
                Title = "Mrs"
            },
            new People()
            {
                FirstName = "Jack",
                LastName = "Jones",
                Title = "Dr"
            }
        };

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.select = selectListItems;
            return View(people);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model List<People>

<form method="post">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model[i].FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model[i].FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model[i].LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model[i].LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model[i].Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="@Model[i].Title" asp-items="@ViewBag.select" class="form-control"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

    }

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Demo**

[image]

From above image, Each contact will have the default selected value based on the value of it's Title.

Comment: Hi @Mark C, Can this answer solved your issue?