dropdown MVC don't keep focus for selected option
I have asp net core mvc application. After clicking filter controller recives propper data, but drop down always shows All option:
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
IsOpenFilterState isOpenFilter = ViewBag.IsOpenFilter;
SortState sortState = ViewBag.SortState;
int currentPage = ViewBag.CurrentPage;
int pagesNumber = ViewBag.PagesNumber;
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form method="get" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="isOpenFilter">Filter by IsOpen:</label>
        <select id="isOpenFilter" name="isOpenFilter" class="form-control">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="OpenOnly">Open</option>
            <option value="ClosedOnly">Closed</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sortState" value="@sortState" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="@currentPage" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
</form>

How to pass selected attribute to selected option?
Or is there a better way to write it?

I think you'll just need "asp-for".... you can also create the selectlist options in your controller... check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc


I have asp net core mvc application. After clicking filter controller
recives propper data, but drop down always shows All option. How to
pass selected attribute to selected option? Or is there a better way
to write it?

Based on your scenario and description, in order to ensure a dropdown list retains its selected value after form submission, we should consider few steps:
In short, after submission need to build a SelectList or a similar structure that allows specifying which option should be pre-selected.
Upon receiving the submitted value in controller, pass the SelectList or the list of options to the view, along with the current selected value.
Finally, in the view, use a dropdown helper method, I am  using  Html.DropDownList  to render the dropdown list. This method takes care of setting the selected attribute on the appropriate option based on the value provided.
Let's have look in practice, how we could implement that. Instantly,two ways spinning around my head.
Way: 1:
Demo Model:
public class DemoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
}

View Model:
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string IsOpenFilter { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IsOpenFilterOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DemoItem> Items { get; set; } 
}

Demo Static data:
private static List<DemoItem> items = new List<DemoItem>
{
    new DemoItem { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1", IsOpen = true },
    new DemoItem { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2", IsOpen = false },
    new DemoItem { Id = 3, Name = "Item 3", IsOpen = true },
    new DemoItem { Id = 4, Name = "Item 4", IsOpen = false }
};

Controller:
public IActionResult Index(string isOpenFilter = "All")
{

    var options = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "All", Text = "All" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "OpenOnly", Text = "Open" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "ClosedOnly", Text = "Closed" }
    };


    IEnumerable<DemoItem> filteredItems = items;

    //Filtering dropdown
    if (isOpenFilter == "OpenOnly")
    {
        filteredItems = items.Where(i => i.IsOpen);
    }
    else if (isOpenFilter == "ClosedOnly")
    {
        filteredItems = items.Where(i => !i.IsOpen);
    }
    //Bind into viewModel
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        IsOpenFilter = isOpenFilter,
        IsOpenFilterOptions = options,
        Items = filteredItems
    };


    return View(viewModel);
}

View:
@model MyViewModel

<form method="get" asp-action="Index2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="isOpenFilter">Filter by IsOpen:</label>
        <select asp-for="IsOpenFilter" asp-items="Model.IsOpenFilterOptions" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Is Open</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.IsOpen</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Output:



Way: 2:
Demo Model:
public class DemoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
}

Controller:
public class DropdownSelectedController : Controller
{
    private static List<DemoItem> items = new List<DemoItem>
    {
        new DemoItem { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1", IsOpen = true },
        new DemoItem { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2", IsOpen = false },
        new DemoItem { Id = 3, Name = "Item 3", IsOpen = true },
        new DemoItem { Id = 4, Name = "Item 4", IsOpen = false }
    };
        public IActionResult Index(string isOpenFilter = "All")
        {
            ViewBag.IsOpenFilter = isOpenFilter;
    
            IEnumerable<DemoItem> filteredItems = items;
    
            if (isOpenFilter == "OpenOnly")
            {
                filteredItems = items.Where(i => i.IsOpen);
            }
            else if (isOpenFilter == "ClosedOnly")
            {
                filteredItems = items.Where(i => !i.IsOpen);
            }
    
            ViewBag.IsOpenFilterOptions = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "All", Text = "All" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "OpenOnly", Text = "Open" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "ClosedOnly", Text = "Closed" }
            }, "Value", "Text", isOpenFilter);
    
    
    
            return View(filteredItems);
        }
    }

Note: I am using isOpenFilter parameter to specify which option should be selected by default when the dropdown is rendered.
View:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    string isOpenFilter = ViewBag.IsOpenFilter ?? "All";
    SelectList isOpenFilterOptions = ViewBag.IsOpenFilterOptions as SelectList;
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form method="get" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="isOpenFilter">Filter by IsOpen:</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("isOpenFilter", isOpenFilterOptions, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Is Open</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.IsOpen</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Output:




